# Pointer to pointer as a function argument in C ( func(type ***arg) vs func(type *arg[]) )

Tags: c, pointers

I am curious how to pass pointer to pointer in the function as an argument. I checked different question, for example - [C: How to pass a double pointer to a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4339201/c-how-to-pass-a-double-pointer-to-a-function)  , there people discuss that in order to pass pointer to pointer you need to pass pointer to pointer to pointer. e.g
if I have

```
char **lines= malloc(sizeof(char) * MAXWORDNUM);

    int y;
    for (y = 0; y < MAXWORDNUM; y ++)
    {
       lines[y] = malloc(sizeof(char) * MAXWORD);
    }
```

Do I need to declare a function

```
func(char ***lines)
```

?
In my code I created a function in the following way -

```
func(char *lines[])
```

and it still works with

```
**lines
```

So what is the difference between these two ways? Is it correct to create function 
func(char *lines[]) for **lines?

Comment: This function call is a big problem: `malloc(sizeof(char) * MAXWORDNUM);`, because `sizeof(char)` is not the same as `sizeof(char*)`.

Comment: The accepted answer to the question you link (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4339201/c-how-to-pass-a-double-pointer-to-a-function)  shows you how to solve your issue. I tend to close your question as being a duplicate to the question you link. Please explain why your question is different.

Comment: @alk Linked question does not resolve my question which is asking what is the difference between func(char ***lines) and func(char *lines[]) . I explained that in my code I used different way than described in linked question - and it works. My question is a comparison of two ways, while linked question is just about how to pass double pointers...

Answer (score 2):

A function declared such as

```
some_type func(char ***lines);
```

takes an argument that is a pointer to a pointer to a pointer to a `char`.

A function such as

```
some_type func(char *lines[]);
```

taeks an argument that is apointer to a pointer to `char`. In other words, it's the same as

```
some_type func(char **lines);
```

I hope you see the difference?

For the first function, the expression `**lines` is a pointer to `char`, but for the second function the same expression *is* a `char`.

---

If you want emulate pass by reference with a pointer to pointer to some type, and allocate the matrix in the function, it's the first one is what you should do:

```
void func(char ***lines)
{
    *lines = malloc(sizeof(char*) * MAXWORDNUM);
    for (int i = 0; i < MAXWORDNUM; ++i)
        (*lines)[i] = malloc(MAXWORD);
}
```

Note that in the loop you have to use parentheses around `*lines` because of the [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) of the indexing operator `[]` than for the dereference operator `*`.

When you call it, you don't pass a variable declared as a tripple-pointer, instead you pass the address (using the address-of operator unary `&`) of a double-pointer:

```
char **lines;
func(&lines);
```

Comment: ok, thank you. I did a bit different... strangely enough but it worked. Not sure why. but thanks for showing the right way

Answer (score 1):

There is no much difference between `func(char *lines[])` and `func(char **lines)`. Both represents the 2D array.
Let me explain you with a simple example.

```
#include<stdio.h>
// function for printing the char 2D array
void PRINT(char **array,int r) //here i am catching with char **
{
int i;
for(i=0;i<r;i++)
printf("%s\n",p[i]);
}

main()
{
char *array[]={"one","two","three"}; // for example i am taking 3 string. you can get these from user also after allocating memory dynamically.
PRINT(array,3); //were 3 is the no of strings.
}
```

In this function i am using `char *[]`

```
void PRINT(char *array[],int r)
{
int i;
for(i=0;i<r;i++)
printf("%s\n",p[i]);
}
```

For both cases output should be

```
one
two
three
```

Behavior of both `char **array` and `char *array[]` is same. no big differences between them.