# C change the value a void pointer represents

Tags: c, pointers, void-pointers

This is a follow up to this question:
[Having a function change the value a pointer represents in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4844914/c-having-a-function-change-the-value-a-pointer-represents)

As an exercise, I am trying to make a generic function that changes a value in an array of undetermined type. I guess it should look like that.

```
void set_value(void * data, void * value, size_t size, int index){
    void * position = data + index*size;
    *position = *value;
}
```

Of course that does not compile, *position = *value do not use the information of the size of value (here was assume both data and value point to smthg of size_t size).

What I am trying to say to my program is :
"take the chunk of memory of size pointed to by value and copy it at the address pointed to by position"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `memcpy()`.

```
void set_value(void * data, void * value, size_t size, int index){
    void * position = (char*)data + index*size;
    memcpy(position, value, size);
}
```

Note also that arithmetic on void pointers is not valid C, although it may be allowed as a compiler extension. You should cast to `char*` first.

Comment: oh, I was fighting with tutorials on pointers and searching in forums and the answer what that basic. Thx.

Comment: Also, don't forget, pointer arithmetic on void pointers isn't strictly valid C.

Comment: actually, I have no clue about that. what would be the valid way to get the pointer position to the right place ?

Comment: Don't you see how I did it in the answer?

Comment: I did, but I did not understand what the cast to char* does (since position is a void*). Should I ask a new question or is there a simple answer that would fit these comments ?

Comment: Casting to `char*` allows you to do arithmetic on the pointer, since the size of a char is known (it's defined to be 1), and `size_t` represents sizes as multiples of this. `void` doesn't have a size because it represents an unspecified type, so you can't do arithmetic on these pointers.

Comment: That clarifies ! Thx a lot.