# Why pointer argv is not updating?

Tags: pass-by-pointer

Can somebody help me understand why the pointer head is not updated after new() call?

expected: val:0     # call new(), update l0.val to 0
actual: val:253784  # why update l0.val not update by the pointer

https://www.edaplayground.com/x/54Nz

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct _node {
  int val;
  struct _node *next;
} node;

//construct the struct
void new(node *head) {
  //malloc return a pointer, type casting to (node*)
  node *head_l = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));

  if(!head_l) {
    printf("Create Fail!\n"); 
    exit(1); 
  }

  head_l->val = 0;
  head_l->next = NULL;

  printf("head_l->val:%0d\n",head_l->val);

  //why head = head_l doesn't work??
  head = head_l;
  //The line below works
  //*head = *head_l;
}

int main() {
  node l0;
  new(&l0);
  printf("val:%0d\n",l0.val);
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate a little bit? If changing to *(l0.val), it causes compilation error.

Answer (score 0):

Function parameters receive only the value they are passed, not any reference or other connection to the argument. When the function is called, the parameter `head` is set to the value of a pointer to `l0`. Changing `head` does not change `l0`.

Comment: Thanks for your explaination, Eric. "the parameter head is set to the value of a pointer to l0. Changing head does not change l0.", is a little bit abstract, can you elaborate a little bit? I am a beginner on using pointer. Thanks, Tom

Comment: I spent some time, and finally understood what Eric was trying to say.

Answer (score 0):

By referring to the post - [Having a function change the value a pointer represents in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4844914/having-a-function-change-the-value-a-pointer-represents-in-c), I am able to find the root cause.

Let's say Address of **head** is [0x0000_0010] -> node object with NULL.

Address of **head_l** is [0x0003_DF58] -> node object with node.val=0.

head = head_l; only modify **head** from 0x0000_0010 to 0x0003_DF58.

*head = *head_l; modify [0x0000_0010] - the value of head points, to [0x0003_DF58] - the value of head_l points.

The latter one will change the destination value(NULL) to new value(node.val=0).