# Pthreads, confusion with pthread_join(pthread_t, void**)

Tags: c++, c, pthreads, pthread-join

I can't understand why does `pthread_join` takes as 2nd argument `void**` for the return value, whereas `pthread_exit`, which is given the return value, has the return value argument as `void*`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

pthread_join waits for the thread to end, and the resulting value from pthread_exit is stored into *value_ptr. If you want to ignore the result, you can pass NULL for the value_ptr. This is the common C practice of simulating pass by reference by passing a pointer to a variable. See [Passing by reference in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2229498/passing-by-reference-in-c)

The pthread_join returns 0 as the function return value on success; then you know that the thread has been joined, and you can access the value from *value_ptr.

```
void *value = NULL;
if (pthread_join(thread, &value) == 0) {
    // thread has ended, and the exit value is available in
    // the value variable
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Essentially, `pthread_join()` wants to return two peices of information:

- a success/failure indication
- whatever the thread returned (which has a type `void*`)

In C, the typical way a function 'returns' two separate values is to have the function return one of those values normally and to 'return' the ofther value in a location provided by the caller where the caller passes in a pointer to that location. So `pthread_join()`:

- returns success/failure as the function's value
- returns the thread's `void*` result in a caller-provided location that the caller passes a `void**` to.

Note that in `pthread_join()`'s case, the caller-provided location is optional.  NULL can be passed in id the caller isn't interested in that result. Making the caller-provided location optional is a common, by by no means universal, idiom.

`pthread_exit()` doesn't need to use a `void**` as it's argument because that argument isn't a *result* of the function.  So it can simply take the value directly.

Comment: Succintly: The return value is what's passed to `pthread_exit()`, but a location to store the return value is what's passed to `pthread_join()`.