# C passing variable by reference

Tags: c, pass-by-reference

I have the following code:

```
main()
{
 uint8_t readCount;
 readCount=0;
 countinfunc(&readCount);
}

countinfunc(uint8_t *readCount)
{
 uint8_t i;
 i = readCount;
 ....
}
```

Problem is that when it enters in the function the variable `i` has a different value then 0 after the assignment.

Comment: @Karoly Horvath could be casting

Comment: may be automatically made by the builder

Comment: compile with warnings and all will be clear.

Comment: this was just an example, but thanks for observing

Comment: `warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]` and `warning: return type defaults to int`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's because in `countinfunc` the variable is a *pointer*. You have to use the pointer dereference operator to access it in the function:

```
i = *readCount;
```

The only reason to pass a variable as a reference to a function is if it's either some big data that may be expensive to copy, or when you want to set it's value inside the function to it keeps the value when leaving the function.

If you want to set the value, you use the dereferencing operator again:

```
*readCount = someValue;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
countinfunc(uint8_t *readCount)
{
 uint8_t i;
 i = *readCount;
 ....
}
```

Answer (score 3):

replace

```
i = readCount;
```

with

```
i = *readCount;
```

Answer (score 2):

You're setting `i` to the *address* of `readCount`. Change the assignment to:

```
i = *readCount;
```

and you'll be fine.

Comment: I can't believe I didn't try that.

Answer (score 1):

just replace

`i=readCount` 
 by 
`i=*readCount`

You cannot assign `(uint8_t *)` to `uint8_t`

For more on this here is the link below
[Passing by reference in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2229498/passing-by-reference-in-c)