# Counting the number of comparisons for merge sort

Tags: c, mergesort

So this is my code for a merge sort. But I need to find out how many times the comparisons were made during the merge function. For my code, the count output would be 0. How should I change the code to make the counter working?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void merge(int *array,int low, int mid, int high,int count)
{
  int i=low, j=mid+1, n=low, f[high+1];

  while((i<=mid)&&(j<=high)) {
    if(array[i]>array[j]){
          f[n]=array[j];
          j++;
      }else{
          f[n]=array[i];
          i++;
      }
    n++;
    count++;
  }

  if(i>mid)
  while(n<=high) {
    f[n]=array[j];
    n++;
    j++;
    }

  if(j>mid)
  while(n<=high) {
    f[n]=array[i];
    n++;
    i++;
    }
  for(n=low;n<=high;n++)
      array[n]=f[n];
}


void mergesort(int *array, int low, int high,int count)
{
  int mid;
  if(low<high){
      mid=(high+low)/2;
      mergesort(array,low,mid,count);
      mergesort(array,mid+1,high,count);
      merge(array, low, mid, high,count);
     }
} 

int main()
{
  int size,i, count=0, *f;
  scanf("%d", &size);
  f=(int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*size);
  for(i=0;i<size;i++)
    scanf("%d", &f[i]);
  mergesort(f, 0, size-1,count);
  for(i=0;i<size;i++) {
      printf("%d",f[i]);
      if(i==size-1)
        printf("\n");
      else
        printf(" ");
    }
  printf("%d\n", count);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Instead of using `<` or `<=` etc, make a named function `lessThan` and increment the count inside this function.

Comment: Function parameters in C are passed by value. That means, changing the value of a parameter inside a function does not change the original variable that the caller passed in. So the `count` needs to be returned from your function or be passed in as a pointer.

Comment: keep a static variable `counter` and increment it in `mergesort` function

Comment: @kaylum how do I pass the count as a pointer?

Comment: You could also make `merge()` return its count (counting from 0), and do the additions in `mergesort()`.

Comment: To pass the count as a pointer, write the argument as int* count, and increment it with *count++. In the main function, call mergesort with &count (i.e. pass the address of the int count variable).

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way to accomplish this is to have one global variable `count` and you increment that variable each time you have comparison in Mergesort code. Either that or using pointers.

In C when you pass argument to function, that argument gets copied so original will remain unchanged. That's the problem with your code.

Please, read more here: [Why would I pass function parameters by value in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14149959/why-would-i-pass-function-parameters-by-value-in-c)