# Changing the value of something in a function

Tags: c, increment

This is a test case for something larger, which is why it is written the way is. How could I make this bit of code so that a's value would keep incrementing? In my project I call a function that parses a line from a file. I need to set values of a struct to certain values that were set in the function call (the parameters of the function were initialized in the main function, like the code below).

```
int increment(int a)
{
    a++;
    return 0;
}
int main()
{
    int a =0;
    int b =0;
    while( b<5){
        increment(a);
        b++;
        cout << "a is: " << a << ". And b is: " << b << "\n";
    }
    system("PAUSE");
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: In many situations, you would be better off returning the incremented value, as in `int increment(int a) {return a+1;}`. The you call it as `a = increment(a)`.

Answer (score 3):

Pass its address to increment

```
void increment(int *a){
  (*a)++;  
}
increment(&a);
//Using the address of operator pass in the address of a as argument
```

Comment: @Lewis Therin Isn't this just incrementing the pointer; not the value?

Comment: @RichardSchneider Operator precedence? You could be right I haven't done C in ages. I've put the bracket to be explicit.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a pointer: See [Passing by reference in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2229498/passing-by-reference-in-c) for a similar question.

Also, you could just modify your increment function to return the incremented value of a, and call it in main like the following:

a = increment(a);

Answer (score 0):

You could:

- Declare `static int a = 0;` `return a++;`
- Change the signature to `int increment( int* a )` and `return *a++;`
- Declare `a` in file scope of the same source file as `increment()`
- Make `a` global
- Do this in C++ and pass `a` by reference

Answer (score -1):

You are passing `a` by value, so the value of `a` can never be changed.

One solution is:

```
int increment (int a) { return a + 1; }
```

Then in your loop:

```
a = increment(a);
```

Another solution is to pass `a` by reference (a pointer)

```
void increment (int *a) { *a = *a + 1; }
```

and in the loop

```
increment(&a);
```

Comment: 2nd version of `increment` was wrong and have now updated it.