# Pass by reference in C not working

Tags: c, operator-precedence

I am having trouble getting a simple pass by reference to work the way I expect.  Fist off, when I compile, I get the following warning:

```
warning: value computed is not used [-Wunused-value]
```

Second, I expect it to print a 2, not a 1 at the end of the program.

```
$ ./testAdd
1
```

Here is the simple code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void addone(int *j) {
  *j++;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int i = 1;

  addone(&i);

  printf("%d\n", i);

  return 0;
}
```

What is going wrong here?

Comment: @EdS. While, strictly speaking, C has no pass by reference, passing a pointer to a function and changing the value it references is effectively the same thing. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2229498/passing-by-reference-in-c/2229510#2229510) as well.

Comment: @Kninnug: No, it's not.  You're adding a level of indirection, but you are *always* passing your arguments by value.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Operator precedence.  The increment operator binds more tightly than the dereference operator, so your code is semantically equivalent to:

```
*(j++)  // invalid read BTW
```

When you wanted

```
(*j)++
```

Also note that C has no notion of pass by reference; everything is pass by value.  You're passing the address by value.  Indirection != pass by reference.