# How do I send a char* to a function and have it change the contents of the char* in C?

Tags: c, string, reference, char, pointers

I have been trying and searching online for too long without any success. I've tried a lot of the suggested answers but nothing has worked for me.

I want to basically send in a `char*`. It can make it NULL if necessary, but  would rather the function modify a `char*` that already has something.

Example:

```
char *old = "kit";
function(old){ //does stuff and writes "kat" to old}

printf("new = %s", old);
```

And

```
result: new = kat
```

How can I do this?

Thanks

EDIT:

What I'm currently trying:

```
calling_function(char *in){ 
  char **old = NULL;
  function(&old);
  printf("old in calling function is now = %s", *old);
}

function(**old){
  <does stuff to get char *another_string = "kat">
  *old = another_string;
  printf("old is now = %s ", *old);
}
```

And the result is:

```
old is now "kat"
old in calling function is now =
```

and it immediately exist the system with an unspecified error exit(-1) then hangs.

Comment: If you want a function to modify a pointer, you will need to pass a pointer to that pointer.

Comment: You use a char ** in your function prototype.

Comment: Can you give me an example. I've already tried that, but it keeps failing for me an I don't understand why.

Comment: can you show what you've tried so far

Answer (score 2):

A `char*` is nothing more an address that points to some bytes which are then interpreted as a string, how to do what you need really depends on what you need to do.

If you want to change a character of the string then a normal `char*` (non `const`) pointer will be enough:

```
void function(char *data) {
  data[0] = 'a';
}
```

If, instead, you want to replace the whole string with another one (possibly of different length), then you will need to pass the address that contains the address, so that you can directly replace it to a new address (that points to a different string):

```
void function(char **data) {
  *data = strdup("newstring");
  // strdup is used because a string literal must be considered as const
  // otherwise you could invoke UB by modifying the returned string
}

char *value;
function(&value);
```

Answer (score 1):

An example for passing `integer` as reference is here: [Passing by reference in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2229498/passing-by-reference-in-c)

For your example, the value can be changed in the function as below:

```
char *old = "kit";
/* this will print kit */
printf("old = %s",old);
function(old);
/* this will print kat */
printf("updated old = %s", old); 

function(char *old) {
   *old = "kat"
}
```

Comment: No, this does not work unfortunately when I try setting old to another char* in function().

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
char *old = "kit";
```

Can cause trouble because old may point to read-only memory. What you want to do is this:

```
char old[128]; // or however many you need
function(old){ //does stuff and writes "kat" to old // You can use sprintf for this} 

printf("new = %s", old);
```

Which will allocate `old` on the stack, where it can be modified.

Answer (score 0):

You can change your function prototype to

```
void myFunction(char** pold)
```

and within that function, you are free to write

```
*pold = "kat";
```

And call the function like this: `myFunction(&old);`

**But beware; this approach has dangers:**

1) You may leak memory as the previous string (i.e. what was `old` originally pointing to?) may be dangling.

2) `*pold = "kat";` assigns read-only memory to `*pold`. This is because "kat" is probably added to a string literal pool on program startup by the C runtime library. Attempting to modify the string (e.g. `(*pold)[0] = 'K'`) is *undefined behaviour*. Using `*pold = strdup("kat");` circumvents this problem.

Comment: This is exactly what I have right now, but when I try printing out the contents of pold in the calling function, it doesn't write. I use printf("changed = %s", *pold);

Comment: In the contet of my program, it will become even more confusing, but I'll try to post the relative parts in my question above. Just a sec.

Comment: Btw, I'm convinced I'm correct here: see @Jack's answer and I'd have received a flurry of downvotes by now if I were mistaken!

Answer (score 0):

This will take an existing char * and change it.
    char* old = "kit";

```
void changingFunction( char* pointer ) {
    strcpy( pointer, "kat" );
    /* or just pointer[1] = 'a'; */
}

changingFunction(old);
printf("new = %s\n", old);
```

Be careful, though.  Remember that you're essentially dealing with an array, and the function doesn't know the size of the array.  You always want to stay within the bounds of the array.

Consequently, you should make the function more advanced:

```
void changingFunction( char* pointer ) {
    char * newString = "kat";
    strncpy(pointer, newString, strlen(pointer));
}
```

By using strncpy, you ensure that you stay within your bounds, and since you're dealing with a null terminated char*, you can use strlen to find how big your bounds are.

Answer (score 0):

I learned something by trying to answer this question! Here's my program that does the operation:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void f(char* str)
{
    strcpy(str, "kat");
}

int main(void) {
    // char* str = "kit"; // Initializing like this causes a crash!

    char str[4]; // This initialization works
    strcpy(str, "kit");

    f(str);
    printf(str); // Prints "kat"

    return 0;
}
```

There are obvious issues with safety, but what was strange to me is that if you declare `str` using the commented-out line, the program crashes. I didn't realize that initializing a string literal like that gave you a pointer to *read-only memory*. That's very non-obvious to me, so I was confused when my little program crashed.

I think it's important to point out that fact first and foremost because it's central to why a naive solution to the problem wouldn't necessarily work. Interesting.