# Pass by pointer/pass by reference in C

Tags: c, pointers

I know how to pass the pointer in function, I feel that I still confuse with two  terminologies, such as pass by reference and pass by pointer.

I was asked this:

> Write a program that uses pointers to pass a variable x by reference to a 
>   function where its value is doubled. The return type of the function should be void. The 
>   value of the variable should be printed from main() after the function call. The 
>   original value of x is 5.

I wrote the code below. can you tell me which comment number is right according to the question's demand and clear my doubt?

```
#include <stdio.h>
//double pointer
//void double_ptr(int **x_ptr)
//{
 //   **x_ptr *=2;

//}

void double_ptr(int *x_ptr)
{
    *x_ptr *=2;
}


int main()
{
    int x=5;
    int *x_ptr=&x;      // single pointer

    //double_ptr(*x_ptr);  // this is out of question's demand.
    //int**x_x_ptr=&x_ptr;    // double pointer
    //double_ptr(&x_ptr);     // 1. pass with double pointer
    //double_ptr(x_x_ptr);      //2. pass with double pointer
    //printf("%d",**x_x_ptr); //3.print with double pointer

    double_ptr(x_ptr);     //4.pass by pointer?
    //double_ptr(&x);          //5.pass by reference?
    printf("%d",*x_ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Pure C doesn't support "pass by reference". You are either passing a value (`f(x)`), or passing the value of the pointer to a value (directly via `f(&x)` or via `int *xp = &x; f(xp);`). So if you're asked to give an example of passing by reference, the terminology is being used very loosely and may simply mean the `f(&x)` case.

Comment: To clarify, C doesn't have references, so when someone says "pass by reference" _in the C language_ they really mean "pass by pointer"

Comment: see here for a nice tutorial http://www.codingunit.com/c-tutorial-call-by-value-or-call-by-reference

Comment: Everyone honest is confused since addresses have been declared values by some language designers living on an island. From there comes the distraction, that an instance referenced by a pointer should be called "by-value". Before this, terms were straight. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/procedures/passing-arguments-by-value-and-by-reference

Comment: @lurker do not agree. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2229498/passing-by-reference-in-c

Comment: @SamGinrich the accepted answer to this question as well as the one you linked agree with what I said in my comment: standard C does not support pass by reference. It's pass by pointer or by value. Sometimes I've seen the pointer passing referred to as a "reference" but that's not the same thing.

Comment: @lurker I'm aware that people draw back to the technical layer, where there is a pointer on a stack, but that's only half of the answer I referenced. In context of that question the answer states "Yes [calling by reference is possible]" and "it is done by passing the pointer to the value". So I don't agree with your conclusion, that passing a pointer excludes the "pass by reference" semantics, actually *x_ptr above (embedding C into C++ terminology) **is** a reference. You can't avoid passing the reference, when you pass the pointer of some [in/out] value.

Comment: @SamGinrich maybe it's semantics, but whether it's a reference or a pointer is mostly about how the language manages the type at programmer's level. C doesn't have references as a type available to the programmer, with the specific behaviors, in the same sense that, for example, C++ does.

Comment: @SamGinrich perhaps consider: http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/z6vU7k9E/

Comment: @lurker I won't send you to articles. Read them all. The use case is calling a method and share values, which is technically done by a pointer, also in C++

Comment: @SamGinrich I think I understand what you are saying. Generically speaking, if you are passing an address, the address *refers* to a value (stated in the vernacular) and thus it is a *reference*. But from a definition in computer languages, *by reference* has more meaning than that. Here's one very simple difference. If I pass a pointer to a function, it would be very wise of me in that function to check if the pointer is NULL. If I pass a reference, no such check is required since a reference, by definition in the language, cannot be null.

Comment: @lurker sure, common reference semantics in C++ suggests, that you can assume a reference to be defined by some instantiated value and thus not being a null reference. Else you can construct a reference from a pointer (in C++ e.g. int * p; int& r = *p), it can be *(int * )0 and on access will raise a null pointer ecception. I.e. pointer and reference behave equivalent, where the precise equivalence is between ´int * const p´ and ´int & r´, when &r==p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass by pointer is actually pass by value, there is no such concept of passing by reference in C.

In C, pass by reference == pass by pointer.

```
void double_ptr(int *x_ptr)
{
      *x_ptr *=2;
}
int main()
{
      int x=5;
      double_ptr(&x); /* a value is being passed*/
}
```

Pass by reference (in C++):

```
void double_ptr(int& x_ptr)
{
   x_ptr *=2;
}
int main()
{
     int x=5;
     int &x_ptr=x;
     double_ptr(x_ptr); /* no temporary is being created i.e. no extra memory allocation is here*?
}
```

Comment: Try compile second version code in a C compiler like GCC, show this error: `error: expected ‘;’, ‘,’ or ‘)’ before ‘&’ token
 void double_ptr(int& x_ptr)` which means C does not support defining a function like that.

Comment: Concepts of passing values and sharing values existed long time ago. In the C-version of double_ptr(), *x_ptr actually is a reference (accordingly in C++ you can initialize a reference with it). Now, to say that referenced **integer** is passed by value appears awkward to me: For this you need to confuse the integer with the pointer to it.