# Using variables from later function in main, C

Tags: c, function, printf

I am having trouble getting the ROBX and ROBY variables to print in the main function. This is a small portion of my program and I do not know what I am doing wrong. Thanks!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#define ROW 8
#define COLUMN 8

int robot (int m[ROW][COLUMN], int ROBX, int ROBY);
int ROBX;
int ROBY;

int main(void)
{
    printf("%d %d\n", ROBX, ROBY);
    return 0;
}
int robot (int m[ROW][COLUMN], int ROBX, int ROBY)
{   
    // ensure different output each time program is run
    srand ( time(NULL) );    
        // Pick a random spot to place the robot
        int placed = 0;
        int ROBX;
        int ROBY;
        while(placed == 0) 
        {
            int t = rand() % ROW;
            int y = rand() % COLUMN;
            if(m[t][y] == 0) 
            {
                m[t][y] = -2;
                placed = 1;
                ROBX = t;
                ROBY = y;
            }
            return ROBX, ROBY;
        }
}
```

Comment: So what's the error that you're getting.

Comment: Isn't your program supposed to call the `robot()` function at some point?

Comment: How Does The Comma Operator Work? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/54142/how-does-the-comma-operator-work]

Comment: `int ROBX; int ROBY;` in `robot()` hides the global definitions of those variables. `return ROBX, ROBY;` doesn't do what you think it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several problems with your code.

For one thing, you never call `robot`, so none of those modifications to your variables are happening.

For another, you're not allowed to return multiple values from a function: The line `return ROBX, ROBY;` is NOT doing what you think it's doing.

Finally, your function doesn't make a lot of sense. You intend to pass in `ROBX` and `ROBY` as parameters. That won't work the way you think it will, but it's not a terrible idea in general. But when you create local variables also called `ROBX` and `ROBY`. As commenters have noted, that will hide both the global variables and the parameters, so you end up only modifying those locally-defined variables.

There are two ways you can fix this:

1. Don't create local variables and don't pass parameters. Just modify the global variables directly.
2. Still don't create local variables, and make your function accept two `int *` parameters. This will allow you to pass in the global variables when you call `robot`, so you can modify those parameters in a persistent way. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2229498/passing-by-reference-in-c) question for more details.

In either case, you will need to actually *call* your `robot` function.