# C does not support passing a variable by reference. How to do it?

Tags: c++, c, pointers, reference

Here is C++ code:

```
void Foo(char* k, struct_t* &Root)
```

how to implement it in pure C?

Comment: Why don't you simply send a pointer's pointer?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: so pass a pointer to the variable, and there's your "reference"

Comment: Behind the scene references are fundamentally pointers, the only difference is that the language doesn't tolerate `null` references and you don't have to use pointer-specific syntax to handle them. As C doesn't support references, use pointers instead. Since your referenced variable is also a pointer, use pointer to pointer, as `struct struct_t** Root`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2229498/passing-by-reference-in-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, C does not support passing by reference (as it is defined by C++). However, C supports passing pointers.

Fundamentally, pointers are references. Pointers are variables which store the memory address at which a variable can be located. Thus, standard pointers are comparable C++ references.

So in your case, `void Foo(char *k, struct_t* &Root)` would be similar to `void Foo(char *k, struct_t **Root)`. To access the `Root` structure within the `Foo` function, you could then say something like:

```
void Foo(char *k, struct_t **Root){
    // Retrieve a local copy of the 1st pointer level
    struct_t *ptrRoot = *Root;
    // Now we can access the variables like normal
    // Perhaps the root structure contains an integer variable:
    int intVariable = ptrRoot->SomeIntegerVariable;
    int modRootVariable = doSomeCalculation(intVariable);
    // Perhaps we want to reassign it then:
    ptrRoot->SomeIntegerVariable = modRootVariable;
}
```

Thus, just passing pointers is equivalent to passing a reference.