# Breaking out of a loop from within a function called in that loop

Tags: c, for-loop, break

I'm currently trying to figure out a way to break out of a `for` loop from within a function called in that loop. I'm aware of the possibility to just have the function return a value and then check against a particular value and then break, but I'd like to do it from within the function directly.

This is because I'm using an in-house library for a specific piece of hardware that mandates the function signature of my function to look like this:

```
void foo (int passV, int aVal, long bVal)
```

I'm aware that not using a return value is **very bad practice**, but alas circumstances force me to, so please bear with me.

Consider following example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void foo (int a) {
    printf("a: %d", a);
    break;
}

int main(void) {
    for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
        foo(i);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Now this does not compile. Instead, I get a compilation error as follows:

> prog.c: In function 'foo': 
>   prog.c:6:2: error: break statement not
>   within loop or switch   break;

I know what this means (the compiler says that the break in `foo()` is not within a `for` loop)

Now, what I could find from the standard regarding the break statement is this:

> The break statement causes control to pass to the statement following
>   the innermost enclosing while, do, for, or switch statement. The
>   syntax is simply break;

Considering my function is called from within a `for` loop, why doesn't the break statement break out of said for loop? Furthermore, is it possible to realise something like this without having the function return first?

Comment: **innermost enclosing while, do, for, or switch statement** what it's find is the enclosing function, so error.

Comment: Look up "longjmp". Or, which might be better advice, don't.

Comment: @ThomasPadron-McCarthy Im working with multiple proprietary functions in a larger project and im afraid I don't have a choice.

Comment: What's wrong with putting `break` right after the call to `foo` ?

Comment: Using `longjmp()` would almost surely require much more work than adding a return result that can be checked. If you'd modify the function to add the `break`, why the resistance to modifying it to return a result?

Comment: @MichaelWalz I need logic available only within foo to break out of it. foo is also mandated to return void by my project

Comment: @Magisch the requirement of returning void sounds really strange to me. You should discuss this with the person responsanble for this somewhat questionable decision.

Comment: @MichaelWalz I know its bad coding practice, but unfortunately I cannot ask the person that wrote this as they already left and I have no way of modifying this

Comment: @Magisch source code no more available ? OMG.

Comment: @MichaelWalz Alternative would be rewriting what once was supposedly a good 80k lines of code ;)

Comment: Are you allowed to change the signature of `foo()`? If so you could pass the return value via pointers. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2229498/passing-by-reference-in-c for more information.

Comment: Downvoted, since THIS is the best example for people insisting on using `goto` patterns, in the way that discredited `goto` to the reuputation it has today. I'm an advocate of using `goto` when there is a real benefit from it. And **THIS** makes me cry.

Comment: @Zaibis I don't want to code this way, but constraints in the in-house library and hardware driver im using force me to.

Comment: What happens if you want to call `foo` from somewhere else in your code that isn't a loop? What would you expect the `break` statement to do there?

Comment: @rhughes I would check against that not happening, but in the example, UB

Comment: @Magisch OK, so you would have some code like: `void foo(bool isInLoop) { if( isInLoop) break; }` ?

Comment: @rhughes Roughly. The implementation I went with uses a Longjump with a similar statement. Two of them, actually, and which one to use (if at all) is passed in a variable.

Comment: @Magisch what you saying sounds inconsistent! given that you have no way of changing `foo()`'s structure while it is part of code which you aren't able (by effort) to rewrite. Assumption: you can't know your "structure" will internally be called. Given this is the case, it might happen `foo()` will be called without `setjmp` beeing invoked before. What is UB. So actually you say the unit tests are fine. but realize: If my assumption is correct, you are risking **UB! DONT DO THIS!** While should I assume wrong, than you should just rewrite the code instead. So w/e: **THIS** approach is wrong.

Comment: @Zaibis Im not sure what exactly causes the constraint, what im saying is directly from the doc of the library. I assume its because its called from assembler code (there is ALOT of interweaved assembler making up the library) and expects a certain function structure. I don't even have access to all the assembler code so I cannot dig through to test. So far the unit tests I've done look promising though, and considering how much of a clustertruck this process already is, I may not have a choice to do it differently.

Comment: @Zaibis Completly elaborating all constraints would probably break SO format by quite a bit, so im trying to be reductive here. The question also explicitly states that the code above is wrong/does not compile, so I fail to see how its bad that above code is incorrect.

Comment: @Zaibis Basicly, I am able to set a jump and use that jump, and I am able to determine wether or not it should use that jump. The function is called from within the library, too, and so thats why there is a mandated signature. Presently im just happy that it works and will do more extensive testing.

Comment: @Magisch: I'm just saying, you are using a structure that you can't change.This means your own code is depending on the lib code. This if you are coding well, just can be caused, because your function will be somway used internally. And as you just admited clearly in your last comment, you can't fully understand this internal code. So you can't exclude the case that your function(`foo()`) might be called internally. and should this happen without an previous `setjmp` (what probably isn't respected by the lib) you will cause undefined behavior. and thats why I try to say you shouldn't use this.

Comment: @Magisch: the problem with undefined behavior is that just testing won't help, since it might go many times right but just some days starts behaving diferent for no reason.

Comment: @Zaibis Presently the jump instruction only happens when I pass a very specific value as parameter, one that should be reasonably never passed by the library, if that happens, I guess im just boned. But dems the breaks in working with partially available badly made code in a language you dont understand by another apprentice 10 years ago.

Comment: @Zaibis Its a sad fact of the situation, but I've had to use many things that would make any good programmer vomit already (like upwards of 40 global variables)

Comment: Your should also state whether there is any chance of your code having to be thread-safe, and perhaps whether you call it directly or indirectly, e.g. is it in reality a call-back function that you pass into a library.

Comment: @PJTraill I must admit I cannot state any of the above with certainty as I only have part of the source code of the library and some documentation written by an apprentice 10 years ago. Its a mine field, I know. I kept the question very general on purpose to avoid trying to delve into an unsolveable highly specific mess of code that would make legit programmers vomit.

Comment: @Magisch You could always use a global variable to fake a return value here, and make it 41.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`break`, like `goto`, can only jump locally within the same function, but if you absolutely have to, you can use `setjmp` and `longjmp`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <setjmp.h>

jmp_buf jump_target;

void foo(void)
{
    printf("Inside foo!\n");
    longjmp(jump_target, 1);
    printf("Still inside foo!\n");
}

int main(void) {
    if (setjmp(jump_target) == 0)
        foo();
    else
        printf("Jumped out!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

The call to `longjmp` will cause a jump back to the `setjmp` call. The return value from `setjmp` shows if it is returning after setting the jump target, or if it is returning from a jump.

Output:

```
Inside foo!
Jumped out!
```

Nonlocal jumps are safe when used correctly, but there are a number of things to think carefully about:

- Since `longjmp` jumps "through" all the function activations between the `setjmp` call and the `longjmp` call, if any of those functions expect to be able to do additional work after the current place in execution, that work will simply not be done.
- If the function activation that called `setjmp` has terminated, the behaviour is undefined. Anything can happen.
- If `setjmp` hasn't yet been called, then `jump_target` is not set, and the behaviour is undefined.
- Local variables in the function that called `setjmp` can under certain conditions have undefined values.
- One word: threads.
- Other things, such as that floating-point status flags might not be retained, and that there are restrictions on where you can put the `setjmp` call.

Most of these follow naturally if you have a good understanding of what a nonlocal jump does on the level of machine instructions and CPU registers, but unless you have that, *and* have read what the C standard does and does not guarantee, I would advise some caution.

Comment: In this example, where is longjmp jumping to and how can I set that?

Comment: `longjmp` jumps back to the `setjmp` call. The return value shows if it is returning after setting the jump target, or if it is returning from a `longjmp` jump.

Comment: Oooh nice, this looks like exactly what I wanted :) Thank you very much

Comment: @Magisch:  I'm curious how `setjmp`/`longjmp` would reduce the 'rewrite' necessary as compared to returning a vale to be checked?  Using `setjmp`/`longjmp` will require both the call site and the function to be modified.  Adding a return value is the same in many cases - except that only call sites that need to be able to perform the `break` need to be modified.  Other call sites can just continue to call the function and ignore the return value.

Comment: @MichaelBurr In a different part of the code that I cannot modify yet have to run regardless is a (very badly made) check that any functions I write for this project can only return void. I would slap the guy that wrote this but he's no longer here.

Comment: @Magisch I still don't understand why you can't modify that badly written part to return something else than void, but you _can_ modify it introducing the setjmp/longjmp fuzz.

Comment: @MichaelWalz I can modify an earlier part, but not the part where it checks the function against it. I do have the source code for the other parts, but im not allowed to modify it (dont ask me why, it has to do with that the other guy left a while ago).

Comment: @Magisch but you still need to modify that part for `setjmp`.

Comment: That part, yes. But the function will be called (and checked against the fact that it has to be void) later in the code that I cannot modify. I will use the input value to the function to determine wether or not to jump, since I suppose that you can't make a int returning function pretend it returns void.

Comment: @Magisch "I suppose that you can't make a int returning function pretend it returns void". Yes  you can. You can call a function returning an `int` exactly as if it was a `void` function. In that case the return value will simply be ignored.

Comment: @MichaelWalz Even if the code calling it assumes on every call that it is indeed a void? Can you concieve of an example where a non-returning function returning something could cause a crash?

Comment: @Magisch you are using this everyday each time you call [`printf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/) which returns an `int` (total number of characters written) but which is ignored almost all the time. You will _never_ get a crash by ignoring the return value of a function. This behaviour is perfectly defined.

Comment: @MichaelWalz: On the source code level, yes, you can just ignore the returned value. But as far as I have understood it this concerns compiled code inside the library he is using?

Comment: @ThomasPadron-McCarthy Yes, a library which I have limited source access to and which I'm not allowed to modify. So I really have no idea but in the documentation it says specifically that the function of that name (the one im writing) has to return void. Im not sure what kind of weird tomfoolery happens in this, as it has a lot of interweaved assembler within (its a hardware driver lib for a specialised piece of hardware).

Comment: @Magisch: beware that you might still be breaking the code despite the fact that you've worked around the explicit requirement for a void-return. If your function "must return void", then your former colleague's code might in particular have been written on the assumption that it "must return" at all. But you've now written a function that doesn't return, it jumps out instead. Check very carefully that your colleague didn't write clean-up code which you're now jumping past, because if so then skipping it likely will cause resource leaks, or leave some data structures in an inconsistent state.

Comment: @Magisch: Especially having read your latest comment, I would want to be a bit careful stomping around with longjumps in this program. But if it's the only way, and careful testing fails to find any problems, then perhaps you can cross your fingers and hope for the best. Just tell me which type of airplane this will be installed in, so I know which flights to avoid...

Comment: @ThomasPadron-McCarthy So far unit tests I've run using the longjump have worked properly. When I changed the function to return int and tested against that I got a segfault on the end of the first call to it.

Comment: @Magisch: that's plausible, reasons I can think of that would happen include that the "assembler tomfoolery" makes a call direct to the C function from assembly (and therefore requires it to have a particular return type) or else that somewhere along the line a pointer to the function is reinterpreted as a pointer to a function of particular signature (and therefore a call to it from C via that function pointer requires it to have the right return type).

Comment: @SteveJessop I don't have the complete assembler source code and I don't understand enough of it to confirm your suspicions but its working properly so far with the longjump function. Memory leak also seems to be not happening.

Comment: Might be worth adding a big "This is usually a very bad idea" warning on top of this answer.

Comment: This is a terrible, terrible idea -1

Comment: @ThomasPadron-McCarthy If you care, its a specialised type of barcode scanner with integrated data processing on our end.

Comment: @ThomasPadron-McCarthy: You shuould also add a note that performing `longjmp` without having set `setjmp` is undefined behavior. So this is anyway not the goal you want to set, in cases you handle with given code structures you are not aware of where else they might be unaware get called, are you with me?

Comment: @Ixrec: Well, I wouldn't go as far as to say that it's "usually a very bad idea". It can be, sometimes, but I've used longjmp with good results in some of my programs. (Granted, I didn't jump through other code that I didn't have control over.) setjmp/longjmp is part of C, with well-defined behaviour. Unless you do it wrong. Then you'd better have bullet-proofed your feet, as usual with C...

Comment: @ThomasPadron-McCarthy: Is the second part of your last comment addressed to me? If so, yeah it is part of it and there is well-defined behavior if used correctly. But note that OP is expressing he has to hand this structure to the library part. means he hasn't absolute controll of when is function maybe gets called. And therefor this answer fits in the cathegory "Unless you do it wrong." So after ignoring my last comment jsut to notify you: this is worth dowvoting to me, and I will do so untill you add this informational.

Comment: @Zaibis: Sorry for ignoring you. But I've added some warnings now.

Comment: @Zaibis I know its a dirty fix that has potential pitfalls and could blow up on me, but thats what im looking for currently.

Answer (score 46):

You cannot use `break;` this way, it must appear inside the body of the `for` loop.

There are several ways to do this, but neither is recommended:

- you can exit the program with the `exit()` function.  Since the loop is run from `main()` and you do not do anything after it, it is possible to achieve what you want this way, but it as a special case.
- You can set a global variable in the function and test that in the `for` loop after the function call.  Using global variables is generally not recommended practice.
- you can use `setjmp()` and `longjmp()`, but it is like trying to squash a fly with a hammer, you may break other things and miss the fly altogether.  I would not recommend this approach.  Furthermore, it requires a `jmpbuf` that you will have to pass to the function or access as a global variable.

An acceptable alternative is to pass the address of a `status` variable as an extra argument: the function can set it to indicate the need to break from the loop.

**But by far the best approach in C is returning a value to test for continuation**, it is the most readable.

From your explanations, you don't have the source code for `foo()` but can detect some conditions in a function that you can modify called directly or indirectly by `foo()`: `longjmp()` will jump from its location, deep inside the internals of `foo()`, possibly many levels down the call stack, to the `setjmp()` location, bypassing regular function exit code for all intermediary calls.  If that's precisely what you need to do to avoid a crash, `setjmp()` / `longjmp()` is a solution, but it may cause other problems such as resource leakage, missing initialization, inconsistent state and other sources of undefined behavior.

Note that your `for` loop will iterate `101` times because you use the `<=` operator.  The idiomatic `for` loop uses `for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)` to iterate exactly the number of times that appears as the upper (excluded) bound.

Comment: It  should be emphasized that evaluating a return value is absolutely the way to go, as it yields best readability.

Answer (score 9):

(Note: the question has been edited since I originally wrote this)

Because of the way C is compiled it must know where to break to when the function is called. Since you can call it from anywhere, or even somewhere a break makes no sense, you cannot have a `break;` statement in your function and have it work like this.

Other answers have suggested terrible solutions such as setting a global variable, using a `#define` or longjumping(!) out of the function. These are extremely poor solutions. Instead, you should use the solution you wrongly dismiss in your opening paragraph and return a value from your function that indicates the state that you want to trigger a `break` in this case and do something like this:

```
#include <stdbool.h>

bool checkAndDisplay(int n)
{
    printf("%d\n", n);
    return (n == 14);
}

int main(void) {
    for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
        if (checkAndDisplay(i))
            break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Trying to find obscure ways to achieve things like this instead of using the correct way to achieve the same end result is a surefire way to generate dire quality code that is a nightmare to maintain and debug.

You mention, hidden in a comment, that you must use a void return, this is not a problem, just pass the break parameter in as a pointer:

```
#include <stdbool.h>

void checkAndDisplay(int n, bool* wantBreak)
{
    printf("%d\n", n);
    if (n == 14)
        wantBreak = true;
}

int main(void) {
    bool wantBreak = false;
    for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
        checkAndDisplay(i, &wantBreak);
        if (wantBreak)
            break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Since your parameters are fixed type I suggest you use a cast to pass in the pointer to one of the parameters, e.g. `foo(a, b, (long)&out);`

Comment: Hardware and software constraints force me to not use a return value. Its clearly listed as a constraint in my question, so why do you suggest I ignore a software constraint? That wont work for me.

Comment: In specific my project uses a inhouse driver/library on specific hardware that has a special constraint stating the function I write _has_ to return void, if you read the comment discussion in the accepted answer you'll get to know exactly why.

Comment: It's helpful if you include the constraint in your question rather than hiding it in a comment. I have added a section about having a void return.

Comment: I specifically discuss that I want an alternative to using return values in my question, is that not enough? If you want to get hyper-specific to my use case (not helpful for future visitors imo but ok) the function is mandated by the library to have the format `void foo (int passV, int aVal, long bVal)` The doc for the library specifically mentions this and not using it makes the program crash with a segfault. I've tried it.

Comment: No, because you don't state it is a requirement; it just sounds like you're ignorant.

Comment: Alright, I included the specific constraint in the question.

Comment: Do you require all three arguments for parameters you're passing in? If not, I would use a cast'd pointer as one of the arguments so you can use it as a return value, e.g. `foo(a, b,(long)&out)`.

Comment: The data types are mandated. Are you suggesting I misuse one of my parameters to pass a pointer instead? I may be able to do that if I work two of my parameters into one using a bit of bitshifting and then untangle them from within the function.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I'm suggesting - sorry, I made a typo in my comment (now corrected).

Comment: I still think a static global variable will be much easier than tangling pointers...

Comment: @Falco Im not sure I can do that without alot of additional overhead (declaring it across multiple files) and in the program itself I already have about 40 global variables. I know its a mess.

Comment: I don't see the problem with multiple files? If you declare the variable in the same file as the function, it should be accessible in the same way as your function is accessible... And the only place where you need to access it is right after the function call `if (function_x_result) break;`

Comment: While I'll accept that occasional global variables are required, using them for this kind of function specific avoidance strikes me as a bad practice. You can swizzle/unswizzle the arguments in a wrapping function and so, for the caller, it could be completely transparent.

Comment: You seriously think mangling a pointer to `long` is a better idea than using a standard, *defined* part of the language like `setjmp`?

Comment: @Magisch You wouldn't need to swizzle parameters, surely? Just make it a pointer to a `struct`. (You'd still need the platform-specific pointer-to-long conversion)

Comment: @Leushenko: It's not undefined behaviour, providing you ensure the pointer type is large enough to hold the resulting value (C 2011 standard, 6.3.2.3). Since Magisch is writing code for a specified platform this is not a concern.

Answer (score 8):

`break` is statement which is resolved during compile time. Therefore the compiler must find appropriate for/while loop within the same function. Note that there is no guarantee that the function couldn't be called from somewhere else.

Comment: Is it possible to emulate this functionality somehow? (Cancelling the for loop from within another function)?

Comment: @Magisch : You can for example return bool/int to indicate that you want to break and then invoke break from the for loop according to return value.

Comment: Im afraid I can't use a return value for this. Is there a different method?

Comment: @Magisch : Well, longjmp is an option but requires special handling and is really expensive. In C++ you can use exceptions but they're quite expensive as well. So rather think about how to reorganize the code. Any solution will require special handling for both the caller and callee so return value (either real return or via pointer) is still best option.

Answer (score 6):

If you cannot use the `break` instruction you could define a local variable in your module and add a second run condition to the `for` loop. For example like the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

static bool continueLoop = true;

void foo (int a)
{
    bool doBreak = true;

    printf("a: %d",a);

    if(doBreak == true){
        continueLoop = false;
    }
    else {
        continueLoop = true;
    }
}
int main(void) {
    continueLoop = true;   // Has to be true before entering the loop
    for (int i = 0; (i <= 100) && continueLoop; i++)
    {
        foo(i);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Note that in this example this is not exactly a `break`-instruction, but the `for`loop will not do another iteration. If you want to do a `break` you have to insert an `if`-condition with the variable `continueLoop` which leads to `break`:

```
int main(void) {
    continueLoop = true;   // Has to be true before entering the loop
    for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++)
    {
        foo(i);
        if(!continueLoop){
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Of course this is the correct answer. Asking "how do you terminate a for loop?" `for (;CONDITION;)` is like asking "how do you terminate a while loop?" `while(CONDITION)`. Note the large bold CONDITION  :)

Answer (score 4):

I believe it's related to how a `break` statement is translated into machine code. The `break` statement will be translated as a unconditional branch to the label immediately following the loop or switch.

```
mov ECX,5
label1:
  jmp <to next instruction address>  ;break
loop label1
<next instruction>
```

While the call to `foo()` from inside the loop will result in something like

```
mov ECX,5
label1:
  call <foo address>
loop label1
<next instruction>
```

and at `foo` address

```
call <printf address>
jmp <to where?> ;break cannot translate to any address.
```

Answer (score 4):

This is another idea that may or may not be feasible: keep a variable around that can turn foo into a no-op:

```
int broken = 0;

void foo (int a) {
    if (broken) return;

    printf("a: %d", a);
    broken = 1; // "break"
}

int main(void) {
    for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
        foo(i);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This is functionally the same except for some loss of clock cycles (the function will be called, but perform only the `if` statement), and there is no need to change the loop. It's not threadsafe and only works the first time (but `foo` could reset the `broken` variable to 0 if called with `a` equal to 0, if needed).

So not great, but an idea that wasn't mentioned yet.

Comment: *if* appropriate you can just put it in the condition of the for.  `for(blah; i<101 && whatever(); ++i)`

Comment: I assumed that the for loop was in code not under his control, that was the only way his problem made sense to me.

Answer (score 4):

In a case like this consider using a while() loop with several conditional statements chained with && instead of a for loop. Although you *can* alter the normal control flow using functions like setjmp and longjmp, it's pretty much considered bad practice everywhere. You shouldn't have to search too hard on this site to find out why. ( In short it's because of it's capacity to create convoluted control flow that doesn't lend itself to either debugging or human comprehension )

Also consider doing something like this:

```
int foo (int a) {
    if(a == someCondition) return 0;
    else {
        printf("a: %d", a);
        return 1;
    }
}

int main(void) {
    for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
        if(!foo(i)) break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

In this case, the loop depends on a true value being returned from 'foo', which will break the loop if the condition inside 'foo' is not met.

Edit: I'm not explicitly against the use of goto, setjmp, longjmp etc. But I think in this case there is a much simpler and more concise solution available without resorting to these measures!

Answer (score 4):

If you cannot handle return values, can you at least add a Parameter to the function:
I can imagine a solution like that:

```
void main (void)
{
  int a = 0;

  for (; 1 != a;)
  {
    foo(x, &a);
  } 
}

void foo( int x, int * a)
{
  if (succeeded)
  {
    /* set the break condition*/
    *a = 1;
  }
  else
  {
    *a = 0;
  }
}
```

It's my first post, so, please forgive me, if my formatting is messed up :)

Comment: @Magisch Sorry, didn't see that.

Answer (score 3):

Following your updated question clearly setting out the limitations, I would suggest you move the entire loop inside your function and then call a second function with a return value inside that function, e.g.

```
#include <stdbool.h>

bool foo (int x)
{
    return (x==14);
}

void loopFoo(int passV, int aVal, long bVal)
{
   for (int i = 0; i <= 100; ++i)
   {
       if (foo(x))
           break;
   }
}
```

This avoids any extreme and fragile gymnastics to get around the limitation.

Answer (score 3):

Just set a global variable and check that on the loop:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int leave = 0;

void foo (int a) {
    printf("a: %d", a);
    leave = 1;
}

int main(void) {
    for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
        foo(i);
        if (leave)
          break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what possible reason would you have to make the variable global?  `for(blah; I<101 & !leave; ++i)`

Comment: @joe blow because the question states that the inner function declaration can't be changed to accommodate a return value. where is 'leave' declared in your one-liner?

Comment: sorry, I meant as a function, like `i<101&&!leave()`  Anyway look - you're quite right, the question is odd

Answer (score 2):

Consider inlining your function manually in the `for` loop. If this function is called in multiple loops, define it as a macro:

```
#define f()\
printf("a: %d", a);\
break;
```

Comment: Thanks for [making](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/35404220/6) my answer invalid. Really rewarding.

Answer (score 2):

You can throw an error in your function inside the loop and catch that error outside the loop.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void foo (int a) {
    printf("a: %d", a);
    if (a == 50)
    {
       throw a;
    }
}

int main(void) {
    try {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
            foo(i);
        }
    catch(int e) {
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This question has already been answered, but I think it is worth delving into all of the possible options to exit a loop in c++. There are basically five possibilities:

- Using a loop condition
- Using a `break` condition
- Using a `return` condition
- Using exceptions
- Using `goto`

In the following, I will describe use cases for these options using c++14. However, you can do all of these in earlier versions of c++ (except maybe exceptions). To keep it short, I will omit the includes and the main function. Please comment, if you think some part needs more clarity.

## 1. Using a loop condition

The standard way to exit a loop is a loop condition. The loop condition is written in the middle part of a `for` statement, or between the parentheses of a `while` statement:

```
for(something; LOOP CONDITION; something) {
    ... 
}
while (LOOP CONDITION)
    ... 
}
do {
    ... 
} while (LOOP CONDITION);
```

The loop condition decides if the loop should be entered, and if the loop should be repeated. In all of the above cases, the condition has to be `true`, for the loop to be repeated.

As an example, if we want to output the number from 0 to 2, we could write the code using a loop and a loop condition:

```
for (auto i = 0; i <= 2; ++i)
    std::cout << i << '\n';
std::cout << "done";
```

Here  the condition is `i <= 2`. As long as this condition evaluates to `true`, the loop keeps running.

An alternative implementation would be to put the condition into a variable instead:

```
auto condition = false;

for (auto i = 0; !condition; ++i) {
    std::cout << i << '\n';
    condition = i > 2;
}
std::cout << "done";
```

Checking the output for both versions, we get the desired result:

```
0
1
2
done
```

**How would you use a loop condition in an real world application?**

Both versions are widely used inside c++ projects. It is important to note, that the first version is more compact and therefore easier to understand. But the second version is usually used if the condition is more complex or needs several steps to be evaluated.

For example:

```
auto condition = false;
for (auto i = 0; !condition; ++i)
    if (is_prime(i))
        if (is_large_enough(i)) {
            key = calculate_cryptographic_key(i, data);
            if (is_good_cryptographic_key(key))
                condition = true;
        }
```

## 2. Using a `break` condition

Another simple way to exit a loop, is to use the `break` keyword. If it is used inside the loop, the execution will stop, and continue after the loop body:

```
for (auto i = 0; true; ++i) {
    if (i == 3)
        break;
    std::cout << i << '\n';
}
std::cout << "done";
```

This will output the current number, and increment it by one, until `i` reaches a value of 3. Here the `if` statement is our `break` condition. If the condition is `true`, the loop is broken (note the `!`) and the execution continues with the next line, printing `done`.

Doing the test, we indeed get the expected result:

```
0
1
2
done
```

It is important, that this will only stop the innermost loop in the code. Therefore, if you use multiple loops, it can lead to undesired behaviour:

```
for (auto j = 0; true; ++j)
    for (auto i = 0; true; ++i) {
        if (i == 3)
            break;
        std::cout << i << '\n';
    }
std::cout << "done";
```

With this code we wanted to get the same result as in the example above, but instead we get an infinite loop, because the `break` only stops the loop over `i`, and not the one over `j`!

Doing the test:

```
0
1
2
0
1
2
...
```

**How would you use a `break` condition in an real world application?**

Usually `break` is only used to skip parts of an inner loop, or to add an additional loop exit.

For example, in a function testing for prime numbers, you would use it to skip the rest of the execution, as soon as you found a case where the current number is not prime:

```
auto is_prime = true;
for (auto i = 0; i < p; ++i) {
    if (p%i == 0) { //p is dividable by i!
        is_prime = false;
        break; //we already know that p is not prime, therefore we do not need to test more cases!
    }
```

Or, if you are searching a vector of strings, you usually put the maximum size of the data in the loop head, and use an additional condition to exit the loop if you actually found the data you are searching for.

```
auto j = size_t(0);
for (auto i = size_t(0); i < data.size(); ++i)
    if (data[i] == "Hello") { //we found "Hello"!
        j = i;
        break; //we already found the string, no need to search any further!
    }
```

## 3. Using a `return` condition

The `return` keyword exits the current scope and returns to the calling function. Thus it can be used to exit loops, and in addition, give back a number to the caller. A common case is to use `return` to exit a loop (and its function) and return a result.

For example, we can rewrite the `is_prime` function from above:

```
auto inline is_prime(int p) {
    for (auto i = 0; i < p; ++i)
        if (p%i == 0) //p is dividable by i!
            return false; //we already know that p is not prime, and can skip the rest of the cases and return the result
    return true; //we didn't find any divisor before, thus p must be prime!
}
```

The `return` keyword can also be used to exit multiple loops:

```
auto inline data_has_match(std::vector<std::string> a, std::vector<std::string> b) {
    for (auto i = size_t(0); i < a.size(); ++i)
        for (auto j = size_t(0); j < a.size(); ++j)
            if (a[i] == b[j])
                return true; //we found a match! nothing to do here
    return false; //no match was found
}
```

**How would you use a `return` condition in an real world application?**

Inside smaller functions, `return` is often used to exit loops and directly return results. Furthermore, inside larger functions, `return` helps to keep the code clear and readable:

```
for (auto i = 0; i < data.size(); ++i) {
    //do some calculations on the data using only i and put them inside result
    if (is_match(result,test))
        return result;
    for (auto j = 0; j < i; ++j) {
        //do some calculations on the data using i and j and put them inside result
        if (is_match(result,test))
            return result;
    }
}
return 0; //we need to return something in the case that no match was found
```

Which is much easier to understand, than:

```
auto break_i_loop = false;
auto return_value = 0;
for (auto i = 0; !break_i_loop; ++i) {
    //do some calculations on the data using only i and put them inside result
    if (is_match(result,test)) { //a match was found, save the result and break the loop!
        return_value = result;
        break;
    }
    for (auto j = 0; j < i; ++j) {
        //do some calculations on the data using i and j and put them inside result
        if (is_match(result,test)) { //a match was found, save the result, break the loop, and make sure that we break the outer loop too!
            return_value = result;
            break_i_loop = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!break_i_loop) //if we didn't find a match, but reached the end of the data, we need to break the outer loop
        break_i_loop = i >= data.size();
}
return return_value; //return the result
```

## 4. Using exceptions

Exceptions are a way to mark exceptional events in your code. For example, if you want to read data from a file, but for some reason the file doesn't exist! Exceptions can be used to exit loops, however the compiler usually generates a lot of boilerplate code to safely continue the program if the exception is handled. Therefore exceptions shouldn't be used to return values, because it is very inefficient.

**How would you use an exception in an real world application?**

Exceptions are used to handle truly exceptional cases. For example, if we want to calculate the inverse of our data, it might happen that we try to divide by zero. However this is not helpful in our calculation, therefore we write:

```
auto inline inverse_data(std::vector<int>& data) {
    for (auto i = size_t(0); i < data.size(); ++i)
        if (data[i] == 0)
            throw std::string("Division by zero on element ") + std::to_string(i) + "!";
        else
            data[i] = 1 / data[i];
}
```

We can the handle this exception inside the calling function:

```
while (true)
    try {
        auto data = get_user_input();
        inverse = inverse_data(data);
        break;
    }
    catch (...) {
        std::cout << "Please do not put zeros into the data!";
    }
```

If `data` contains zero, then `inverse_data` will throw an exception, the `break` is never executed, and the user has to input data again.

There are even more advance options for this kind of error handling, with additional error types, ..., but this is a topic for another day.

** What you should never do! **

As mentioned before, exceptions can produce a significant runtime overhead. Therefore, they should only be used in truly exceptional cases. Although it is possible to write the following function, please don't!

```
auto inline next_prime(int start) {
    auto p = start;
    try {
        for (auto i = start; true; ++i)
            if (is_prime(i)) {
                p = i;
                throw;
            }
   }
   catch (...) {}
   return p;
 }
```

## 5. Using `goto`

The `goto` keyword is hated by most programmers, because it makes code harder to read, and it can have unintended side effects. However, it can be used to exit (multiple) loops:

```
for (auto j = 0; true; ++j)
    for (auto i = 0; true; ++i) {
        if (i == 3)
            goto endloop;
        std::cout << i << '\n';
    }
endloop:
std::cout << "done";
```

This loop will end (not like the loop in part 2), and output:

```
0
1
2
done
```

**How would you use a `goto` in an real world application?**

In 99.9% of the cases there is no need to use the `goto` keyword. The only exceptions are embedded systems, like an Arduino, or very high performance code. If you are working with one of these two, you might want to use `goto` to produce faster or more efficient code. However, for the everyday programmer, the downsides are much bigger than the gains of using `goto`.

Even if you think your case is one of the 0.1%, you need to check if the `goto` actually improves your execution. More often than not, using a `break` or `return` condition is faster, because the compiler has a harder time understanding code containing `goto`.