# How to change the value of pointer in C

Tags: c

I have a function which take a `char *str` and `const char a` as parameters and change every single `a` in `*str` to `'X'`. Since I can't modify the value pointer point to like `*str = 'X'`. How I am going to do this problem?

Comment: Why do you say you can't do `*str = 'X'`?

Comment: The code that calls the function should ensure to pass a mutable buffer

Comment: You might find http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2229498/passing-by-reference-in-c helpful.

Comment: If it took `char cons* str`, you wouldn't be able to. But since it takes `char* str`, you can. Try it out.

Comment: Show your code instead of describing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's suppose we have a function like this:

```
int change_char( char *str, const char a, const char b) {
    int n = 0;
    if ( str ) {
        while ( *str ) {
            if ( *str == a ) {
                *str = b; // Can I modify the value pointed by the pointer?
                ++n;
            }
        ++str;  // Can I modify the pointer?
        }
    }
    return n;
}
```

When we call that function, like in the following sample, the pointer is passed by value, so you can't modify the original pointer (only its local copy), but you can modify the value of the object pointed by that pointer:

```
char test[] = "Hello world!";
change_char(test, 'o', 'X');
printf("%s\n",test);   // it will output HellX wXrld!
```

Comment: I used char * tset = "Hello world" in the original test. As a result I always get the same string every time I run it. Could you explain more specific about the difference? Thank you!

Comment: @KevinWei `"Hello world"` is a const string literal, you can use it to initialize a null terminated string with `char test[] = "Hello world!";` and then modify the character in it, but if you declare a pointer like `char *test = "Hello  world"` it will point to a costant and any attempt to modify the chars will result in a run time error. In that case you should allocate memory and then copy the string. See a live example [here](https://ideone.com/0dlUAJ).