# Linked List elements not getting displayed

Tags: c, pointers, data-structures, struct, linked-list

This is my program in C which always inserts into a linked list at the end. But when I try to print the list elements, nothing is displayed. Here is the code :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
struct Node
{
    int data;
    struct Node *next;
};
void insert(struct Node *, int);
int main(void)
{
    struct Node *head = NULL, *current;
    int n, i, x, data;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &data);
        insert(head, data);
    }
    current = head;
    while(current != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d ", current->data);
        current = current->next;
    }
}
void insert(struct Node *head, int data)
{
    struct Node *newnode, *current = head;
    newnode = (struct Node *)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    newnode->data = data;
    newnode->next = NULL;
    if(head == NULL)
    {
        head = newnode;
    }
    else
    {
        while(current->next != NULL)
        {
            current = current->next;
        }
        current->next = newnode;
    }
}
```

I cannot understand what might be the issue. Please help.

Comment: [One of the correction methods](http://ideone.com/VRNVHw)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, while you are passing the `head` pointer to your `insert()` function, it is not being updated in your `main()` function.

So, either declare your `head` pointer as global or return your `head` pointer and update it in your `main()` function.

In the below code I had taken the `head` pointer as global and removed the `head` pointer as your parameter from the `insert()` function.

Here is the code :-

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
struct Node
{
    int data;
    struct Node *next;
};
struct Node *head=NULL;
void insert(int);
int main(void)
{
    struct Node  *current;
    int n, i, x, data;
    clrscr();
    scanf("%d", &n);
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
    scanf("%d", &data);
    insert(data);
    }
    current = head;
    while(current != NULL)
    {
    printf("%d \n", current->data);
    current = current->next;
    }
    getch();
    return 0;
}
void insert(int data)
{
    struct Node *newnode, *current = head;
    newnode = (struct Node *)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    newnode->data = data;
    newnode->next = NULL;
    if(head == NULL)
    {
    head = newnode;
    }
    else
    {
    while(current->next != NULL)
        {
            current = current->next;
        }
        current->next = newnode;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Superb!

Comment: Thank you  @Rahul

Answer (score 3):

Your `insert` cannot modify `head`.  Change it to

`void insert(struct Node **head, int data)`

and change it by

`*head = newnode;`

and call it like this

`insert(&head, data);`

Comment: I think you should also mention how the OP should call the `insert` function.

Answer (score 2):

You need to **pass the reference of** the `head` pointer, then only the changes made to it will be visible.

You must declare your function like

```
void insert(struct Node **, int);
```

and also call it like

```
insert(&head, data);
```

also, make changes to function definition

```
void insert(struct Node **head, int data)
{
    struct Node *newnode, *current = *head;
    newnode = (struct Node *)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    newnode->data = data;
    newnode->next = NULL;
    if(*head == NULL)
    {
        *head = newnode;
    }
    else
    {
        while(current->next != NULL)
        {
            current = current->next;
        }
        current->next = newnode;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the `head` by [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37136552/meaning-of-pass-by-reference-in-c-and-c) as you are making changes to it that should be visible.

```
insert(head, data);
```

should become

```
insert(&head, data);
```

Also the function signature will change.

```
void insert(struct Node *head, int data)
```

should become

```
void insert(struct Node **head, int data)
```

Also make appropriate changes in the function.

Like,

```
current = *head;
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are passing the pointer by value. The function operates on a copy of the pointer, and never modifies the original.

Either pass a pointer to the pointer (i.e. a struct head **), or instead have the function return the pointer.

You can  try running the following code which will give the output as null

```
printf("%s",head);
while(current != NULL)
{
    printf("%d", current->data);
    current = current->next;
}
```

Comment: type of `head` is `struct Node *`, not `char*`.

Comment: If you want to display pointer address, `printf("head is %p\n", (void*)head);`. If you want to confirm that it is just `NULL`, `if(head == NULL) puts("head is NULL");`