# Not working single linked list C

Tags: c, list, pointers

I am too bad now. My list is not working! I know that there is an issue of just coping my ptr into function, not actually using real one, but I can't understand how can I make this work as I want.

PS. I see also that if I make head as global value, it will be ok. But I want to get function, which I can call it specific list.

Here is function of adding element into a blamk list. I can't make even this function work. I tried to play with double pointers, but now I am here to ask some help.

```
   #include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};

void add( int num,struct node * head )
{
    struct node *temp;
    temp=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    temp->data=num;
    if (head== NULL)
    {
    head=temp;
    head->next=NULL;
    }
    else
    {
    temp->next=head;
    head=temp;
    }
}

int  main()
{
    struct node *head;
    head=NULL;
    add(20,head);
    if(head==NULL) printf("List is Empty\n");

    return 0;
}
```

UPD: MY own playing with double pointers:

```
    #include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};

void add( int num, struct node **head )
{
    struct node **temp;
    temp=(struct node **)malloc(sizeof(struct node*));
    (*temp)->data=num;
    if (*head== NULL)
    {
    *head=*temp;
    (*head)->next=NULL;
    }
        else
{
(*temp)->next=head;
*head=temp;
}

}

int  main()
{
    struct node *head;
    head=NULL;
    add(20,&head);
    if(head==NULL) printf("List is Empty\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [casts are bad for malloc - see this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Comment: The use of `head` as a function parameter hides it from the other function. You should have played with double pointers some more.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing by reference in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2229498/passing-by-reference-in-c)

Comment: Inside `add` you change the value of `head`. Try to find a way how to pass the new value of `head` up the caller.

Comment: What happens to `temp` is `head` is not null - kinda disappears - memory leak

Comment: *head=temp;* in the add function doesn't do what you think is doing. The *head* pointer you are passing in the add function is actually a copy of you header. So *head=temp;* doesn't change the original but the copy one. You need to send the address of your header

Comment: `head=temp;` do not do what you intended, it do not actually swap pointer for main head

Comment: I know all these things. I just can't make double pointers work. Sad, but true.

Comment: Draw a diagram - I find this helps.  Pointers being an arrow and the variable being a box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
struct node **temp;
temp=(struct node **)malloc(sizeof(struct node*));
(*temp)->data=num;
if (*head== NULL)
{
    *head=*temp;
    (*head)->next=NULL;
}
```

To

```
struct node *temp;
temp=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
(temp)->data=num;
if (*head== NULL)
{
    *head=temp;
    (*head)->next=NULL;
}
```

The reason you are getting a segmentation fault, is because in malloc, you allocated `sizeof(struct node*)`, which is basically enough size for a pointer and doesn't make any sense to do so.

Also, change the logic of the else in add, if you are planning to add in more nodes.

Answer (score 0):

How do you expect it will work if you don't pass the address of `head` to the function?

Correct code:
`add(20,&head)`

And you also have to change your function signature with this:
`void add(int num, struct node **head)`

Also, to refer to your `struct node` pointer, again in the `add` function you'll want to change `head` with `*head`.

Please pay attention: `**head` points to `*head`, so everytime you want to apply changes to your pointer (not *double pointer*) `head`, you have to tell it to the compiler by using `*head`.

Comment: I tried such way. I get segfault. I am very bad today. I am so confused.

Comment: Then please post your code and the errors you get, so that it will be simplier for us to help you.

Comment: In this actual code I still see that you use `head` instead of `*head` in your `add` function.

Comment: `head = (struct node **) head;` also remove this.

Comment: Could you add the output with this final version of your code?

Answer (score 0):

How are you expecting it to work? It wont work unless you pass the pointer `head` itself, here you are just creating a copy of it. You can do this as well.

```
head = add(20,head);
```

Instead of just

```
add(20,head);
```

Add a

```
return head;
```

before ending the function

And don't forget to change the return type of your function like this

```
struct node* add( int num,struct node *head)
```

The updated code looks like this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};

struct node* add( int num,struct node *head)
{
    struct node *temp;
    temp=malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    temp->data=num;
    if (head==NULL)
    {
        head=temp;
        head->next=NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        // please change your logic
    }
    return head;
}

int  main()
{
    struct node *head;
    head=NULL;
    head = add(20,head);
    if(head==NULL) printf("List is Empty\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Cheers!

Comment: well, it is great idea. But I have played with double pointers too much. So, I want make them work too.

and what is bad with logic in else?

And I know that my code should not work! I just gave an example for u to play :)

Comment: @Dida Haha, I didn't know you did it purposefully.