# How to create a file in a function and use it in other functions

Tags: c

The file is created, but the function WriteFile can't write in the file, I need to create the file in a function not in the main.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    void CreateFile(FILE *file){
        file = fopen("file.txt","w");
        if(file == NULL){
            printf("Error : Could not create the file");
        }
    }
   void WriteFile(FILE *file){
        fprintf(file,"Hello !");
    }

    int main()
    {
        FILE *file = NULL;
        CreateFile(file);
        WriteFile(file);
        fclose(file);
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: The value of `file` is "forgotten" right after `CreateFile` is returning.

Comment: You should define the function like this (following @Eugene Sh.'s comment) `FILE *CreateFile(FILE *file)`. This function will return the file descriptor which you can use it later .

Comment: @EugeneSh. what can I do to solve this problem ?

Comment: Pass it a `FILE **` parameter. Or return the file descriptor as a return value.

Comment: @EugeneSh.: Why make a 2-star programmer where 1 is sufficient?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing by reference in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2229498/passing-by-reference-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Eugene Sh, you don't keep the pointer to the file you create. This fixes it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

FILE *CreateFile(void){
    FILE *file = fopen("file.txt","w");
    if(file == NULL){
        printf("Error : Could not create the file");
        exit(1);
    }
    return file;
}

void WriteFile(FILE *file){
    fprintf(file, "Hello !");
}

int main(void)
{
    FILE *file = CreateFile();
    WriteFile(file);
    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}
```

Or, if you want to send the variable `file` from main into the function, use a double pointer:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void CreateFile(FILE **file){
    *file = fopen("file.txt","w");
    if(*file == NULL){
        printf("Error : Could not create the file");
    }
}

void WriteFile(FILE *file){
    fprintf(file, "Hello !");
}

int main(void)
{
    FILE *file = NULL;
    CreateFile(&file);
    WriteFile(file);
    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *minor*: it should be `FILE *CreateFile(void)`

Comment: OP didnt have void as return value on fucntions so I stuck with a "modern" C style and excluded void there...

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "modern", but the "modern" standard does require `void` if a function takes no arguments.

Comment: I've always compiled my C code without `void`... gcc 4.4.7 is the oldest I've used.

Comment: Hehe thanks, I knew strictly that it is required, but I came to C from Java and like(d) the visuals of empty parentheses ;)

Comment: Thanks @Olaf, I should avoid the use of "reference" as a literal English word in this context.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not the file, it's your use of the pointers. In C, function parameters are passed by value : It means that in your code when you call `CreateFile(file);` you are giving the value of `file`, which is `NULL`.
You have two possibilities to fix this, you can use a double pointer :

```
void CreateFile(FILE **file);
```

Calling the function like this :

```
FILE *file;
CreateFile(&file);
```

Or you can `return` the value from `CreateFile()` :

```
FILE *CreateFile(void);
FILE *file = CreateFile();
```

(Edit : I did not see @Hans Petter Taugbøl Kragset's answer ...)