# Pop function in a stack (C)

Tags: c, stack, singly-linked-list

I am having some issues with my `pop()` function in this program. This is an implementation of stack as singly linked list, and as you can see the pop function has two arguments:

> void pop(STACK *stack, char **name)

I am told to: allocate memory for `name` in the `pop` function and return the `name` or `NULL` using the `**name` argument. I have tried several things, yet I don't understand what this actually means, and also how to do that since the function doesn't return anything (`void` type). Generally I am having trouble understanding this `**name` argument, and why would be we even want to use that in the first place. Here is my code so far:

```
typedef struct _stack STACK;
typedef struct _sElem stackElement;

struct _stack{
    stackElement *head;
};

struct _sElem{
    char *name;
    stackElement *next;
};

//solved:
void pop(STACK *stack, char **name){
    if(stack == NULL || stack->head == NULL){
        printf("Stack is empty. \n");
    }else{
        stackElement *temp = stack->head;
        char **nodeName = malloc(sizeof(char*));
        char *tempName = temp->name;
        (*nodeName)=tempName;
        (*name) = (*nodeName);
        stack->head = temp->next;
        free(temp);
    }
}

int main(){
    STACK *myStack = NULL;
    char *tempName = NULL;

    push(myStack, "One");
    push(myStack, "Two");
    push(myStack, "Three");
    pop(myStack, &tempName);
    pop(myStack, &tempName);

    //free stack and tempName

    return 0;
}
```

I appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing by reference in c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2229498/passing-by-reference-in-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Generally I am having trouble understanding this **name argument, and
>   why would be we even want to use that in the first place.

Because in C all parameters are passed by value.  So if you your function was defined as `void pop(STACK *stack, char *name)` instead and you assigned the value of `name` inside `pop` it would not be visible to the caller after `pop` returned.

Instead, if you define your function as: `void pop(STACK *stack, char **name)`, then you can assign to `*name` so the caller has access to the new value.

For instance:

```
STACK *head = ...
char *name = NULL;
pop(head, &name);
if (name != NULL)
{
   fprintf(stdout, "Popped name: %s\n", name);
   free(name);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, do I also have to allocate memory for the name in the pop function as `char *name = malloc(sizeof(char))` or something?

Comment: yep.  but you need to allocate the correct size.  :)