# linked list c programming error by inserting new element

Tags: c, linked-list

I am trying to insert an element but it get the error "Process finished with exit code 11"

```
struct node {
    int key;
    struct node *next;
};
struct node* init(){
    struct node *head =NULL;
    return head;
}
void create(struct node * head,int num) {
    struct node * tmp = head;
    struct node * prev = NULL;
    struct node* new = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    new->key = num;
    prev = tmp;
    tmp = tmp->next;
    while(tmp!= NULL && tmp->key < num){
        prev = tmp;
        tmp = tmp->next;
    }
    new->next = tmp;
    prev->next = new;
    if (tmp== NULL)
        head=tmp;
    }
int main() {
    int num;
    struct node* head;
    head=init()
    printf("Enter data:");
    scanf("%d",&num);
    create(head,num);
}
```

i am trying to insert an element into a linked list and the element should be sorted and entered at the same time.can someone tell me that the error is ? i cannot seem to find out the error.

Comment: Did you try to run your code under debugger? On what line an error appears?

Comment: A node is no list. A list is no node.

Comment: tmp = tmp->next; i am having the error here

Comment: how can i correct it?

Comment: @GeorgeJose Sorry, but since there is no list in your code, there is no easy fix.

Comment: `tmp = tmp->next` why do you think you should be able to do this? There is a condition that must hold before you can use  the `->` operator, do you know what it is? have you checked that it holds?

Comment: `init()` is literally 0; why not `struct node *head = 0;` (or `NULL`.) One probably wants to check the return value of `scanf`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2229498/passing-by-reference-in-c.

Answer (score -1):

It's not clear what your function `create()`

> ```
> void create(struct node * head, int num) {
>   struct node * tmp = head;
>   struct node * prev = NULL;
>   struct node* new = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
>   new->key = num;
>   prev = tmp;
>   tmp = tmp->next;
>   while (tmp != NULL && tmp->key < num) {
>       prev = tmp;
>       tmp = tmp->next;
>   }
>   new->next = tmp;
>   prev->next = new;
>   if (tmp == NULL)
>       head = tmp;
> }
> ```

is supposed to do. You effectively pass it a `NULL` pointer and return `void`, so everything it does is meaningless to the outside world.

The<sup>tm</sup> starting point for every no bs linked list implementation:

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct node_tag {
    int value;
    struct node_tag *next;
} node_t;

// write functions to encapsulate the data and provide a stable interface:

node_t* node_create_value(int value)
{
    node_t *new_node = calloc(1, sizeof *new_node);
    if(new_node) new_node->value = value;
    return new_node;
}

node_t* node_advance(node_t const *node) { return node->next; }


typedef struct list_tag {  // a list usually consists of
    node_t *head;          // a pointer to the first and
    node_t *tail;          // a pointer to the last element
    // size_t size;        // one might want to add that.
} list_t;

list_t list_create(void)
{
    list_t list = { NULL, NULL };
    return list;
}

// make code based on these functions "speak" for itself:

node_t* list_begin(list_t const *list) { return list->head; }
node_t* list_end  (list_t const *list) { return list->tail; }
bool list_is_empty(list_t const *list) { return !list_begin(list); }

// common operations for lists:

node_t* list_push_front(list_t *list, int value)
{
    node_t *new_node = node_create_value(value);
    if (!new_node)
        return NULL;

    new_node->next = list->head;
    return list->head = new_node;
}

node_t* list_push_back(list_t *list, int value)
{
    // push_back on an empty list is push_front:
    if (list_is_empty(list))
        return list->tail = list_push_front(list, value);

    node_t *new_node = node_create_value(value);
    if (!new_node)
        return NULL;

    list->tail->next = new_node;
    return list->tail = new_node;
}

node_t* list_insert_after(list_t *list, node_t *node, int value)
{
    if (list_end(list) == node)
        return list_push_back(list, value);

    node_t *new_node = node_create_value(value);
    if (!new_node)
        return NULL;

    new_node->next = node->next;
    return node->next = new_node;
}

node_t* list_insert_sorted(list_t *list, int value)
{
    // first handle the special cases that don't require iterating the whole list:

    if (list_is_empty(list) || value < list_begin(list)->value)
        return list_push_front(list, value);

    if (value > list_end(list)->value)
        return list_push_back(list, value);

    // the general (worst) case:

    for (node_t *current_node = list_begin(list); node_advance(current_node); current_node = node_advance(current_node))
        if (value < node_advance(current_node)->value)
            return list_insert_after(list, current_node, value);

    return NULL; // should never happen
}

void list_print(list_t const *list)
{
    for (node_t *current_node = list_begin(list); current_node; current_node = node_advance(current_node))
        printf("%d\n", current_node->value);
}

void list_free(list_t *list)
{
    for(node_t *current_node = list_begin(list), *next_node; current_node; current_node = next_node) {
        next_node = current_node->next;
        free(current_node);
    }
}

// user code should not be required to know anything about the inner workings
// of our list:

int main(void)
{
    list_t list = list_create();
    for (int i = 1; i < 10; i += 2) {
        if (!list_push_back(&list, i)) {
            list_free(&list);
            fputs("Not enough memory :(\n\n", stderr);
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
    }

    list_print(&list);
    putchar('\n');

    for (int i = 0; i < 11; i += 2) {
        if (!list_insert_sorted(&list, i)) {
            list_free(&list);
            fputs("Not enough memory :(\n\n", stderr);
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
    }

    list_print(&list);
    list_free(&list);
}
```

#### Output:

```
1
3
5
7
9

0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question in any way, shape, or form.

Comment: @n.m. If that is your opinion downvote away. Plan-B: make suggestions on how to improve it. The code in the question is fubar.

Comment: The question seems to be about an error that code posted by OP has. An improvement plan: remove the code from the answer, explain what the error is, how to fix it, and how to avoid it in the future. Do **not** present an ideal from-the-book answer to the exercise. It is rather unlikely to be helpful to someone who is struggling with basic notions of the language.