# c linked list append insert

Tags: c, linked-list

I want to insert a node int the end of the linked list, but I don't know how to achieve.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Info* PtrToNode;
struct Info {
    int number;
    PtrToNode next;
};
typedef struct Info* list;

typedef struct HashNode* HashTable;
struct HashNode {
    list Heads;
    int size;
};

HashTable createTable(int size) {
    HashTable H = (HashTable)malloc(sizeof(struct HashNode));
    H->size = size;
    H->Heads = (PtrToNode)malloc(H->size * sizeof(struct Info));
    for (int i = 0; i < H->size; ++i)
    {
        H->Heads[i].number = 0;
        H->Heads[i].next = NULL;
    }
    return H;
}

int Hash(int n, int size) {
    return n % size;
}

void insert(HashTable H, int index, int number) {
    int pos = Hash(number, H->size);

    list check = H->Heads[pos].next;
    while (check) {
        check = check->next;
    }
    PtrToNode newNode = (PtrToNode)malloc(sizeof(struct Info));
    newNode->number = number;
    newNode->next = NULL;
    check = newNode;
}
```

I want append in the insert function, but the params "check" like temporary, and if I "while" the H->heads[pos], the node always in the head.

Comment: What is the problem with your actual code? Also, instead of `list check = H-Heads[pos].next;` you should first make sure the list is not empty, then poiunt to the head of the list; that is: `if(H->Heads[pos]) check=H->Heads[pos];`

Comment: You are confusing arrays and lists. `H->Heads[i].number` is not the proper way to access a list. For a list you need `H->Heads->number` and `H->Heads->next`. The `next` pointer will point to the next element of the list

Comment: You are using `for (int i = 0; i < H->size; ++i)` to iterate across a list, which is totally wrong.

Comment: A list usually has a pointer to the first node (`head`) and a pointer to the last node (`tail`). But you are using a node to represent the whole list which obviously lacks `tail`. Without `tail` appending a node to a list is very inefficient. With tail: `tail->next = new_node; tail = new_node;` Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53380533/3975177) for a possible implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing arrays and lists. `H->Heads[i].number` is not the proper way to access a list. For a list you need `H->Heads->number` and `H->Heads->next`. The next pointer will point to the next element of the list

Basically you have an array of numbers with an extra unused pointer.

For the `create` function given to add an element at the end, you need to `realloc` the entire array with new size. However, this is probably not what you want.

You need to modify the `create` function to make a true list and then you can append.

Code below, inserts at the end, you can modify to insert at a particular index.

```
typedef struct Info* PtrToNode;
struct Info {
    int number;
    PtrToNode next;
};
typedef struct Info* list;

typedef struct HashNode* HashTable;
struct HashNode {
    list Heads;
    int size;
};

HashTable createTable(int size) {
    HashTable H = (HashTable)malloc(sizeof(struct HashNode));
    H->size = size;
    H->Heads = malloc(sizeof(struct Info));
    H->Heads->number = 0;
    H->Heads->next = NULL;

    list curr = H->Heads;
    list nextval;

    for (int i = 1; i < H->size; ++i)
    {
        nextval = malloc(sizeof(struct Info));
        nextval->number = 0;
        nextval->next = NULL;
        curr->next = nextval;
        curr = curr->next;
    }
    return H;
}

int Hash(int n, int size) {
    return n % size;
}


void insert(HashTable H, int index, int number) {
    int pos = Hash(number, H->size);

    list check = H->Heads;
    while (check->next)  {
        check = check->next;
    }
    PtrToNode newNode = (PtrToNode)malloc(sizeof(struct Info));
    newNode->number = number;
    newNode->next = NULL;
    check->next = newNode;

    (H->size)++;
}
```

Comment: thanks.
change the "check" to "list check = &H->Heads[pos];", is ok,