# There is a error in deleting a node in a linked list

Tags: c, linked-list

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
    struct Node {
        int data;
        struct Node *next;

    };
void printList(struct Node *n)
{
    while (n!=NULL) {

    printf(" %d|\t", n->data);
    n = n->next;
    }
}


int main () {
    struct Node* head = NULL;
    struct Node* second = NULL;
    struct Node* third = NULL;
    struct Node* fourth = NULL;
    struct Node* fifth = NULL;

    head = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    second = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    third = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    fourth = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    fifth = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));

    head-> data = 1;
    head->next = second;

    second->data = 2;
    second->next = third;

    third->data = 3;
    third->next = fourth; 

    fourth->data = 4;
    fourth->next = fifth;

    fifth->data = 5;
    fifth->next = NULL;

    printList(head);
    delete();
    printList(head);
}
void delete(){
    struct Node* temp;
    int loc;
        printf("Enter the location what you want to delete : ");
        scanf("%d",&loc);
        if(loc>length()){
            printf("Invailid Location");
        }
            else if (loc==1) {

            temp = root;
            root= temp -> next;
            temp -> next = NULL;
            free (temp);
        }
}
```

> ***There is a error in root variable and delete function. It says no deceleration of root variable. And previous implicit declaration of 'delete' was here*** Is it need to declare root variable first? If yes, where is want to be? Please let me know what is the error in this program.

Comment: Read your code again, where is the `root` variable defined?

Comment: Furthermore, how would the `delete` function have access to the list you create in the `main` function?

Comment: your `delete` function should have a parameter that passes your link list.

Comment: Another thing: A node is not a list and a list is not a node. A list typically contains a pointer to the first element (head) and a pointer to the last element (tail) and maybe also the number of elements in the list.

Comment: [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53380109/linked-list-c-programming-error-by-inserting-new-element/53380533#53380533) is a starting point for the implementation of a singly linked list I wrote for a differen question.