# Inserting into a linked list always returns last node, not current node

Tags: c

So I'm writing a program that creates a dinamic list, it inserts a new node after the last node and eventually it prints the freshly created list. I want that when I print it it actually prints the number of the current node in succession (like Info: 1, Info: 2, Info: 3) but it turns out it prints always the last node. I guess it's a pointer error, but can't really find what.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node{
  int info;
  struct node* pNext;
};

typedef struct node Node;

void tail_insertion(Node* pFirst, Node* pLast);
void print_list(Node* pFirst);

static int n=3;

int main()
{
    Node *pFirst=NULL, *pLast=NULL;
    tail_insertion(pFirst, pLast);
}

void tail_insertion(Node* pFirst, Node* pLast){
  // Creation of a new node in the heap
  Node *pNew = (Node*) malloc(sizeof(Node));
  pNew->info=0;
  pNew->pNext= NULL;

  for(int i=0; i<3;i++){
    if(pFirst == NULL){// No node in the list
      pNew->info++;
      pFirst = pNew; // The first node is the newly created one
      pLast = pNew; // The last node is the newly created one
      printf("Ok the list was empty\n");
    }
    else{
      // Else, there is already at least one node in the list
      pNew->info++;
      pLast-> pNext= pNew; // the last node becomes the second one
      pLast= pNew; // The last node is the newly created one
      printf("Ok the list wasn't empty\n");
    }
  }
  print_list(pFirst);
  return;
}


void print_list(Node* pFirst){
  if(pFirst == NULL){
    printf("No node in the list!\n");
  }
  else{
    // New pointer used to scan the list.
    Node* pScan = pFirst;
    do{
      printf("Info: %d\n", pScan->info);
      // ptrScan is updated to point to the next node in the
      // list
      pScan = pScan->pNext;
    }while(pScan!= NULL && --n); //NULL when this was the last node
  }
  return;
}
```

It prints so:

```
Ok the list was empty
Ok the list wasn't empty
Ok the list wasn't empty
Info: 3
Info: 3
Info: 3
```

Comment: Hint: The value of `pFirst` *will not* be changed outside of the function.

Comment: @EugeneSh. What should I do then?

Comment: Why do you need `pLast`? Seems redundant and not checked for errors?

Comment: @NeilEdelman I use that to point at end of the list so I know where to insert the new node

Comment: in your **struct node** you have a node element which points to the next node variable in your linked list, you could use that to find the end of the list.

Comment: @user10835998 You're true!

Comment: Hint: when you do pFirst = pNew you let pFirst point to pNew

Comment: You could have a pointer to a pointer to Node and `tail_insertion(&pFirst);`. `C` is pass-by-value, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2229498/passing-by-reference-in-c

Comment: another hint: you could print the address a pointer is pointing to like so: `printf("pNew address: %p\n", pNew);`

Comment: Thanks for the hints guys

Comment: If you have a structure that requires `pFirst` and `pLast` to always be passed together, you should think about putting them in a single `struct`.

Comment: OT:  regarding: `Node *pNew = (Node*) malloc(sizeof(Node));`  in C, the returned type from any of the heap allocation functions: `malloc` `calloc` `realloc` is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, etc.  2) when calling any of these functions, always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  If not successful, call `perror()` with your error message, cleanup, then call `exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`  Note: `exit()` and `EXIT_FAILURE` are from the header file: `stdlib.h`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two problems:

- you are not passing in pointers to the list pointers (`Node *` -> `Node **`)
- you are trying to insert the **same** `Node` three times (move `malloc()` into the loop)

I guess `static int n = 3` and `while ... && --n)` have probably been added in a desperate attempt to "fix" the endless loop in `print_list()`, because `pscan->pNext` yielded `pscan` in the original code...

Fixed and cleaned up code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node Node;
typedef struct node {
  int   info;
  Node* pNext;
} Node;

static void print_list(Node* pFirst) {
  // New pointer used to scan the list.
  Node* pScan = pFirst;
  while (pScan) {
    printf("Info: %d\n", pScan->info);
    // ptrScan is updated to point to the next node in the
    // list
    pScan = pScan->pNext;
  }
}

static void tail_insertion(Node** pFirst, Node** pLast) {
  for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
    // Creation of a new node in the heap
    Node *pNew  = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    pNew->info  = i + 1;
    pNew->pNext = NULL;

    if (*pFirst == NULL) {    // No node in the list
      *pFirst = pNew;         // The first node is the newly created one
      *pLast  = pNew;         // The last node is the newly created one
      printf("Ok the list was empty\n");
    } else {                  // Else, there is already at least one node in the list
      (*pLast)->pNext = pNew; // the last node becomes the second one
      *pLast          = pNew; // The last node is the newly created one
      printf("Ok the list wasn't empty\n");
    }
  }
  print_list(*pFirst);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  Node *pFirst = NULL;
  Node *pLast  = NULL;
  tail_insertion(&pFirst, &pLast);
}
```

Test run:

```
$ gcc -Wall -Werror -o dummy dummy.c
$ ./dummy
Ok the list was empty
Ok the list wasn't empty
Ok the list wasn't empty
Info: 1
Info: 2
Info: 3
```

Comment: Yeah I added the --n to try fixing the loop. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

### Code fix

Using you own code, you should fix `tail_insertion(...)` to be like the code below. There are comments to help understand the changes.

```
Node *pNew; /* Declaring pNew *without* assignment. */

for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    
    pNew = (Node*) malloc(sizeof(Node)); /* Allocation of new memory address. */
    
    pNew->info  = i; /* pNew->info works like an ID in you current code. */

    pNew->pNext = NULL; /* It is proper to assign NULL */
    
    if(pFirst == NULL){
        
        pNew->info++;
        
        pFirst       = pNew;
        pLast        = pNew;
        
        printf("The list was empty.\n");
        
    } else {
        
        pNew->info++;
        
        pLast->pNext = pNew;
        pLast        = pNew;
        
        printf("The list wasn't empty.\n");
        
    }
}

print_list(pFirst);
```

Note that I have removed the `return(...)` function since it wasn't necessary. It is not necessary because `tail_insertion(...)` has the type `void`.

Also, `pNew->info` is storing the ID of the node as of my reading. So it shouldn't be a problem assigning `i` to it. If necessary, make the proper changes.

Now.. Let's begin explaining things from the beginning!

### General Code Analysis

Let's **consider** `tail_insertion(...)` and what you want it to do:

- You create a new node;
- You give it the right values;
- You start a `for` loop with the intention of creating more nodes based on certain conditions;
- You print the whole list to check if it worked;

Now, look at your **code for** `tail_insertion(...)` **function** (*comments removed*):

```
Node *pNew = (Node*) malloc(sizeof(Node));

pNew->info=0;
pNew->pNext= NULL;

for(int i=0; i<3;i++){
    
    if(pFirst == NULL){
        
        pNew->info++;

        pFirst = pNew;
        pLast = pNew;
        
        printf("Ok, the list was empty.\n");
        
    } else {
        
        pNew->info++;

        pLast-> pNext= pNew;
        pLast= pNew;
        
        printf("Ok, the list wasn't empty.\n");
        
    }
    
}

print_list(pFirst);
```

Seeing any problem yet? No? Well, let's proceed.

### Debugging

We are going to **debug this function step-by-step**. Aside from program fixes, it is important for the learning process as well:

- **Creating a node**:

  - You create `pNEW`. It is empty;
  - Let's give it the address `0x01` (fictious);
  - A `0` is assigned to `pNew->info`;
  - A `NULL` is assigned to `pNew->pNext`;
- **Beginning of the** `for` **loop** - an attempt to create 3 nodes for a list:

  - `i = 0`:

    - You check to see if the list is empty. It is:

      - You add `1` to `pNew->info` value. The address of `pNew` is `0x01`;
      - `pFirst` is assigned to point at the address `0x01`;
      - `pLast` is assigned to point at the address `0x01` since the list was empty;
      - You print a message saying the list was empty;
  - At the end of `i = 0`, the list is as follows:

    - `pFirst` points at the address `0x01`;
    - `pLast` points at the address `0x01`;
    - `0x01->info` is `1`;
  - `i = 1`

    - You check to see if the list is empty. It is not:

      - You add `1` to `pNew->info` value. The address of `pNew` is `0x01`. There was never a creation of another node;
      - `pLast->pNext` is assigned to point at the address `0x01`;
      - `pLast` is assigned to point at the address `0x01`;
      - You print a message saying the list wasn't empty;
  - At the end of `i = 1`, the list is as follows:

    - `pFirst` points at the address `0x01`;
    - `pLast` points at the address `0x01`;
    - `pLast->pNext` points at the address `0x01`;
    - `0x01->info` is `2`;
  - `i = 2`

    - You check to see if the list is empty. It is not:

      - You add `1` to `pNew->info` value. The address of `pNew` is `0x01`. There was never a creation of another node;
      - `pLast->pNext` is assigned to point at the address `0x01`;
      - `pLast` is assigned to point at the address `0x01`;
      - You print a message saying the list wasn't empty;
  - At the end of `i = 2`, the list is as follows:

    - `pFirst` points at the address `0x01`;
    - `pLast` points at the address `0x01`;
    - `pLast->pNext` points at the address `0x01`;
    - `pLast->pNext->pNext` points at the address `0x01`;
    - `0x01->info` is `3`;
  - End of the `for` loop;
- **Printing the resulting list**:

  - A call for `print_list(...)`

### Conclusion

As of now, you probably saw **what's wrong**: you haven't created a new node inside the `for` loop. You created it outside of the loop. This makes a repetitive process of **adding the very same node with the same address to the list**.

Also, you are having problems with the value of `info`. But that is thanks to using the same node as stated above. It will need just some adjusting in this incremental logic that sets `info` value to accommodate the modifications need to fix the usage of the same node and make everything work.

### Final Notes

There are comments saying you don't need `pLast`. While that is true, you need to consider:

- If you only use `pFirst`, you need to make sure that after inserting the new node in `pFirst->pNext`, you do a `pFirst->pNext->pNext = NULL`. This way you can know whenever you have reached the end of the list by comparing to `NULL`;
- If you continue to use `pLast`, you can compare to `pLast` to know if the address is the last address inside the list. Obviously, you can also compare to NULL after my fix;
- **Considering tail insertions**, having `pLast` facilitates things quite a bit and reduces CPU usage in the long run;

You probably know but you should put `print_list(pFirst);` inside the `main(...)` function to makes things more organized. Also, it makes my "code OCD" reach new levels of desperation! ;-)

Comment: Another design decision I would contemplate is head insertions, which allow `pFirst` to be the Single-Source of Truth and allow `O(1)` insertion, basically a stack.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, it's very exhaustive! I now got the flaw.