# Why is the given output produced after running jumbleArrays()?

Tags: c, pointers

I have the following C code:

```
int array_len(int *a) {
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE && a[i] != TERMINATOR; i++);
    return i;
}

void jumbleArrays(int *a1, int *a2)
{
    int a1_len = array_len(a1);
    a2 = a1;
    a2[a1_len] = 42;
    if(a1_len <= ARRAY_SIZE)
        a2[a1_len+1] = TERMINATOR;

    a1 = malloc(sizeof(int) * ARRAY_SIZE);
    a1[0] = 41;
    a1[1] = TERMINATOR;
}

int main() 
{
    int a1[ARRAY_SIZE];
    int a2[ARRAY_SIZE];

    a1[0] = 10;
    a1[1] = 4;
    a1[2] = TERMINATOR;

    a2[0] = 7;
    a2[1] = 9;
    a2[2] = 11;
    a2[3] = TERMINATOR;

    jumbleArrays(a1, a2);

    printf("Contents of a1: ");
    for(int i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE && a1[i] != TERMINATOR; i++) {
        printf("%d ", a1[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    printf("Contents of a2: ");
    for(int i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE && a2[i] != TERMINATOR; i++) {
        printf("%d ", a2[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Why when the program is ran why isn't the output the following?

Contents of a1: 41

Contents of a2: 10 4 42

But instead it is 
Contents of a1: 10 4 42

Contents of a2: 7 9 11

The JumbleArrays is taking a pointer (nothing but an address) and then makes changes to the existing array a1. It then creates a new array on the heap whose base address will be stored in a1, but it seems like after the jumbleArrays() method returns that address is no longer stored in a1? Overall, I'm not sure as to why a1 and a2 refer to their older arrays when clearly they store different addresses in jumbleArrays.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2229498/passing-by-reference-in-c

Answer (score 1):

```
void jumbleArrays(int *a1, int *a2)
{
    int a1_len = array_len(a1);
    a2 = a1;
```

Notice that `a1` and `a2` are pointers and that after that last line, the `jumbleArrays` function no longer knows the address of the `a2` array in `main`. Its variable, though called `a2` now holds the address of the `a1` array. So there is no possible way anything this function does after this line can possibly modify the original `a2` array. So your expectation, that it would change the contents of `a2` cannot be justified. It doesn't even know where `a2` is after this line.

Then we have:

```
a1 = malloc(sizeof(int) * ARRAY_SIZE);
```

After this point, the local `a1` pointer points to some newly-allocated memory and the original pointer to the original `a1` is lost. So nothing after this line can possibly modify the original `a1` array -- we no longer know where it is. So your expectation that the subsequent lines will modify the `a1` array in `main` isn't justified.

Comment: Well I'm not saying its going to modify the original 2 arrays in main. What I don't get is that isn't the jumbleArrays method changing what each pointer stores, ie what array each pointer refers too. We changed the values that a1 and a2 store so why aren't those changes reflected in main when we print their contents?

Comment: @aDabOfRanch The fact that `main` has a variable named `a1` and jumbleArrays` has a variable also named `a1` doesn't connect those two variables in any magic way. One is an array, the other is a pointer. The pointer can be made to point to whatever `jumbleArrays` wants to make it point to, that has no effect on an array it happened to once point to.