# C - Returning a Structure Member from Function

Tags: c

I am writing this code that calculates Miles per Gallon where the number of miles and gallons are read from the keyboard. The program will perform a simple calculation to get the miles per gallon. I wrote a function in order to do this this calculation but it is not returning the result. Inside the function everything is working as it should. I even wrote a `printf` to ensure the calculation was done correctly. But then when I try to return it to the main function, the member of the structure appears to have a value of `0` instead of the result of the calculation. Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct gas {
 float distance;
 float gals;
 float mpg;
};

float CalculateMpg(struct gas idk){
    idk.mpg = idk.distance / idk.gals;
    printf("%f \n", idk.mpg);
    return idk.mpg;
}

int main()
{
    struct gas idk;

    printf("Enter distance (in miles): ");
    scanf("%f", &idk.distance);
    printf("Enter gallons fueled: ");
    scanf("%f", &idk.gals);

    CalculateMpg(idk);
    printf("%f \n", idk.mpg);
    printf("Miles driven gallons used with %.2f miles and %.2f gallons: %.2f mpg \n", idk.distance, idk.gals, idk.mpg);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: C passes by value. I would recommend reading a good book or tutorial if you didn't learn that yet. The 10 new questions about it every day aren't useful. Passing by value means you modify a **copy** of `idk`'s `mpg`, not the member in the one declared in `main()`. But you **return** it, so why not just read that result instead of ignoring it? However, then you don't need to assign to the copy at all, or store `mpg` per-instance, if it can always be calculated on-demand... but if you must, the 2nd option is modify in-place, ie pass via pointer, in which case there's not any point returning too.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing by reference in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2229498/passing-by-reference-in-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Reason: Because C uses call-by-value**

When you call function `CalculateMpg()`, idk is copied to argument variable by value.

In this function, only copied argument is edited.

You should make function uses pointer and call it to `CalculateMpg(&idk)`

Sample Solution:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct gas {
 float distance;
 float gals;
 float mpg;
};

float CalculateMpg(struct gas* idk){
    idk->mpg = idk->distance / idk->gals; // arrow is just syntactic sugar of (*idk).field
    printf("%f \n", idk->mpg);
    return idk->mpg;
}

int main()
{
    struct gas idk;

    printf("Enter distance (in miles): ");
    scanf("%f", &idk.distance);
    printf("Enter gallons fueled: ");
    scanf("%f", &idk.gals);

    CalculateMpg(&idk);
    printf("%f \n", idk.mpg);
    printf("Miles driven gallons used with %.2f miles and %.2f gallons: %.2f mpg \n", idk.distance, idk.gals, idk.mpg);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ahh ok, I understand now. However this code is giving me an error.

Comment: Aw, sorry. i used c++ style reference syntax which is wrong. i've just fixed it.