# How a global variable is defined in this C code

Tags: c, global-variables, cs50

I am undertaking the CS50 course and I came across this issue in problem set 3 with Tideman voting system. My question is not about the algorithm itself but with the variable `ranks` where it is only defined within the main function.

For the solution you can only update the TODO functions and nothing else. Also as part of the solution the `ranks` array has to be updated within the `vote` function. My problem is to understand how is the variable accessed from another function when it's not globally defined?

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

// Max number of candidates
#define MAX 9

// preferences[i][j] is number of voters who prefer i over j
int preferences[MAX][MAX];

// locked[i][j] means i is locked in over j
bool locked[MAX][MAX];

// Each pair has a winner, loser
typedef struct
{
    int winner;
    int loser;
}
pair;

// Array of candidates
string candidates[MAX];
pair pairs[MAX * (MAX - 1) / 2];

int pair_count;
int candidate_count;

// Function prototypes
bool vote(int rank, string name, int ranks[]);
void record_preferences(int ranks[]);
void add_pairs(void);
void sort_pairs(void);
void lock_pairs(void);
void print_winner(void);

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    // Check for invalid usage
    if (argc < 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: tideman [candidate ...]\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Populate array of candidates
    candidate_count = argc - 1;
    if (candidate_count > MAX)
    {
        printf("Maximum number of candidates is %i\n", MAX);
        return 2;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        candidates[i] = argv[i + 1];
    }

    // Clear graph of locked in pairs
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < candidate_count; j++)
        {
            locked[i][j] = false;
        }
    }

    pair_count = 0;
    int voter_count = get_int("Number of voters: ");

    // Query for votes
    for (int i = 0; i < voter_count; i++)
    {
        // ranks[i] is voter's ith preference
        int ranks[candidate_count];

        // Query for each rank
        for (int j = 0; j < candidate_count; j++)
        {
            string name = get_string("Rank %i: ", j + 1);

            if (!vote(j, name, ranks))
            {
                printf("Invalid vote.\n");
                return 3;
            }
        }

        record_preferences(ranks);

        printf("\n");
    }

    add_pairs();
    sort_pairs();
    lock_pairs();
    print_winner();
    return 0;
}

// Update ranks given a new vote
bool vote(int rank, string name, int ranks[])
{
    // TODO
    
    return false;
}

// Update preferences given one voter's ranks
void record_preferences(int ranks[])
{
    // TODO
    return;
}

// Record pairs of candidates where one is preferred over the other
void add_pairs(void)
{
    // TODO
    return;
}

// Sort pairs in decreasing order by strength of victory
void sort_pairs(void)
{
    // TODO
    return;
}

// Lock pairs into the candidate graph in order, without creating cycles
void lock_pairs(void)
{
    // TODO
    return;
}

// Print the winner of the election
void print_winner(void)
{
    // TODO
    return;
}
```

Comment: The variable is passed as an argument to the function. *ranks* is an array defined in the main function, then this array is passed to *vote*, *record_preferences*, and so on.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2229498/passing-by-reference-in-c

Comment: I am putting an effort myself and I'm doing a course. I have searched for arrays but couldn't find anything related
 Also don't think this is a pointers issue or at least not in a form that the link above shows.

Comment: @MoZed : You need to hone your Google-Fu:  https://beginnersbook.com/2014/01/c-passing-array-to-function-example/

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Your title and the only question you ask in the content of your post, aren't related to each other. This line is where it is passed: `if (!vote(j, name, ranks))` btw.

Answer (score 1):

When you pass an *array* as a function parameter, it is *passed by reference* not *by copy*.  So when you access `ranks` in `vote()`, you are accessing the instance of the array in `main()`.

Comment: Thank you @Clifford. Yes this answers my question.