# linked list implementation gives me "command termination"

Tags: c, struct, linked-list

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct node
{
   int data;
   struct node *link;
};

struct node *add_node(struct node *head, struct node *tail);

int main()
{
    struct node *head = NULL, *tail = NULL;
    add_node(head, tail);

    head->data = 2;


    return 0;
}


struct node *add_node(struct node *head, struct node *tail)
{
       if (head == NULL)
       {
          struct node *new_node = (struct node *) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
          head = new_node;
          return new_node;
       }

}
```

I am trying to make a function that starts a empty linked list. But when i try to store the value '2' in the data member of the first node it does not work. I have tested this inside the actual function and successfully stored and printed '2', why does this occur outside the function?

Comment: What would `printf("head: %p\n", head);` before `head->data = 2;` output?

Comment: wow, it gives "(nil)" which means nothing got stored in head

Comment: i think this may be because the new_node variable got destroyed after the function ended or something

Comment: No, the memory was not destroyed. It's just *head* was not updated. When passing a (simple) pointer, you can modify its data but not the address itself. To do that you'd need a double pointer (*struct node \*\*ppHead*), but that's an overkill in this case. Simply use function's return value. *tail* is useless (at this point). Note that at the end you should free the memory. Note that there are tons of such examples on the web.

Comment: Apart from the issue mentioned above `add_node()` should return something in else case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `add_node` deals with copies of the pointers `head` and `tail` declared in main because they are passed to the function by value.

So this statement within the function

```
  head = new_node;
```

changes the function parameter `head` but not the original object `head` declared in main.

Moreover the function does not use its parameter `tail`.

And the function invokes undefined behavior in case when `head` is not equal to `NULL` because in this case it returns nothing.

After this call

```
add_node(head, tail);
```

the both pointers, `head` and `tail`, are still equal to `NULL`. And dereferencing a null pointer

```
head->data = 2;
```

results in undefined behavior.

So truly speaking the function does not make a sense.

You should define one more structure as for example

```
struct list
{
    struct node *head;
    struct node *tail;
};
```

Then in main instead of these declarations

```
struct node *head = NULL, *tail = NULL;
```

you need to write for example

```
struct list lst = { .head = NULL, .tail = NULL };
```

and the function `add_node` can be declared and defined the following way

```
int add_node( struct list *lst, int data )
{
    struct node *new_node = malloc( sizeof( struct node ) );
    int success = new_node != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
        new_node->data = data;
        new_node->link = NULL;

        if ( lst->tail != NULL )
        {
            lst->tail->link = new_node;
        }
        else
        {
            lst->head = new_node;
        }

        lst->tail = new_node;
    }

    return success;
}
```

And in main the function can be called for example like

```
add_node( &lst, 10 );
```

or

```
if ( !add_node( &lst, 10 ) )
{
    puts( "Error: not enough memory." );
}
```

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node
{
   int data;
   struct node *link;
};


struct list
{
    struct node *head;
    struct node *tail;
};


int add_node( struct list *lst, int data )
{
    struct node *new_node = malloc( sizeof( struct node ) );
    int success = new_node != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
        new_node->data = data;
        new_node->link = NULL;

        if ( lst->tail != NULL )
        {
            lst->tail->link = new_node;
        }
        else
        {
            lst->head = new_node;
        }

        lst->tail = new_node;
    }

    return success;
}

int main(void) 
{
    struct list lst = { .head = NULL, .tail = NULL };
    
    if ( add_node( &lst, 10 ) )
    {
        printf( "The head node contains %d\n", lst.head->data );
        printf( "The tail node contains %d\n", lst.tail->data );
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
The head node contains 10
The tail node contains 10
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `add_node` function returns a `struct node *` but in the main function, there is no variable to receive it. Try this.

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct node
{
   int data;
   struct node *link;
};

struct node *add_node(struct node *head, struct node *tail);

int main()
{
    struct node *head = NULL, *tail = NULL;
    head = add_node(head, tail); // notice the change here.
    head->data = 2;
    return 0;
}

struct node *add_node(struct node *head, struct node *tail)
{
    if (head == NULL)
    {
        struct node *new_node = (struct node *) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        head = new_node;
        return new_node;
    }
}
```

Or you can change your `add_node` function to take a reference to a pointer than the pointer itself, like this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct node
{
   int data;
   struct node *link;
};

struct node *add_node(struct node **head, struct node *tail);

int main()
{
    struct node *head = NULL, *tail = NULL;
    add_node(&head, tail);
    head->data = 2;
    return 0;
}

struct node *add_node(struct node **head, struct node *tail)
{
    if (*head == NULL)
    {
        struct node *new_node = (struct node *) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        *head = new_node;
        return new_node;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just like Vlad from Moscow said, you are passing the value of `head`(which is an address) when you call the function `add_node(struct node *head, struct node *tail)`. So at this line: `head = new_node;`, you are changing the value(an address) that was received in the parameter and not the contents of the `head` that's in the `main()` function.

So what do you do? Well consider the code below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


struct node
{
    int data ;
    struct node *nextNode ;         // holds the link to the next node of the linked list
} ;


struct node* createNode(int d)
{
    struct node *new_node = malloc(sizeof(struct node)) ;
    new_node->data = d ;
    new_node->nextNode = NULL ;

    return new_node ;       // returns the address of the newly created node
}


// takes the tail pointer of the linked list and adds a new node to the end of the linked list
struct node* addNode(struct node *tail, int dataOfNewNode)
{
    struct node *new_node = createNode(dataOfNewNode) ;
    
    if(tail != NULL)
    {
        tail->nextNode = new_node ;
    }

    return new_node ;
}


void display(struct node *head)
{
    struct node *temp = head ;

    while(temp != NULL)
    {
        printf("[%d] - ", temp->data) ;
        temp = temp->nextNode ;
    }

    printf("\n") ;
}


int main()
{
    struct node *head, *tail ;

    head = NULL ;
    tail = NULL ;

    head = createNode(2) ;
    tail = head ;           // as there's just one node in the linked list for now

    tail = addNode(tail, 4) ;
    tail = addNode(tail, 6) ;

    display(head) ;

    return 0 ;
}
```

In the code shown above, I've created a function `addNode()` which takes the address of the tail of the linked list and adds to it, then it returns the address of the new node. So, the newly added node becomes the new tail of the linked list. Once again, here the value of the tail is being passed when `addNode()` is called. However if you wish to change the contents of the `head` pointer in the `main()` function itself, have a look at the 2nd code posted by @susanth29.

You might find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2229498/passing-by-reference-in-) helpful.