# change a var using pointer in a function

Tags: c, pointers, pass-by-reference, function-declaration

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

change (int i)
{
    int *x;
    x = &i;
    printf("%d\n",*x);
    *x = 7;
    printf("%d\n",*x);

} 

int main()
{
    int i=66 ; 
    change(i);
    printf("%d\n",i);
    return 0;
}
```

I'm wondering how to change a var value using pointer in a function using C.

Comment: For starters you'd need the function to actually accept a pointer as argument

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2229498/passing-by-reference-in-c

Comment: You could start by writing an actual valid function that compiles cleanly, then take it from there.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the variable `i` to the function by reference.

In C passing by reference means passing an object indirectly through a pointer to it. Thus dereferencing the pointer within the function you can change the original object pointed to by the pointer.

So your function will look like

```
void change (int *p)
{
    printf("%d\n",*p);
    *p = 7;
    printf("%d\n",*p);
}
```

and be called like

```
change( &i );
```

Comment: Surely, Vlad, you can find a duplicate for this.