# Why the values not been updated in Function

Tags: c, function

I was practicing a problem on C but I had a doubt about why the values in Function had not been updated
here is the code that I was practising.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    int i = -5;
    int j = -2;
    fun(i,j);
    printf("i = %d j = %d\n",i,j);
    return 0;
}

void fun(int i,int j){
    i = i * i;
    j = j * j;
    return i,j;
}
```

Please come up with an explanation....!!!!

Comment: The variables you are modifying are local copies of the values passed to the function.

Comment: You can't return values in a function declared to not return a value. And you can only return a single value.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing by reference in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2229498/passing-by-reference-in-c)

Answer (score 3):

```
void fun(int i,int j){
```

`i` and `j` are "local" to the function (pedantically saying they have automatic storage duration) and they will stop to exist when the function returns. They are **not related** to the `i` and `j` variables in function `main`.

To modify `i` and `j` variables in function `main` you need to pass the references to those variables. It is done by using the ***pointers***

```
void fun(int *i,int *j){
    *i = *i * *i;
    *j = *j * *j;
}
```

2. `return i,j;`

- you can only return one value from the function.
- it will not modify any variables in the caller
- your function is `void` and you cant return anything.

```
int fun(int *i,int *j)
{
    *i = *i * *i;
    *j = *j * *j;
    return *i * *j;
}

int main(void)
{
    int i = -5;
    int j = -2;
    int result = fun(&i, &j);
    printf("i = %d j = %d, result = %d\n", i, j, result);
    return 0;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/EvGxjET84

Answer (score 1):

1. Your code returns type `void`, not a pair of integers (there are no pairs in C).
2. Arguments to functions are copied, so you can't modify them inside function. If you want to, then you must use a pointer.

I highly recommend reading some beginner tutorials about C, because these mistakes are very basic.