In Zig (and by extension C), Is pass by reference or pass by value more performant when modifying structs
Given this basic struct for 3d Vectors:
pub const Vec3 = struct {
    x: f32 = 0,
    y: f32 = 0,
    z: f32 = 0,

    pub fn init(x: f32, y: f32, z: f32) Vec3 {
        return Vec3{ .x = x, .y = y, .z = z };
    }

}

Lets say I want to add a scale function, which is the most performant/correct way to accomplish this
Pass By Reference:
pub fn Scale(self: *Vec3, scalar: f32) void {
   self.x = self.x * scalar;
   self.y = self.y * scalar;
   self.z = self.z * scalar;
}

Pass By Value and Return
 pub fn Scale(self: Vec3, scalar: f32) Vec3 {
   return Vec3.init(self.x * scalar, self.y * scalar, self.z * scalar);
}

Obviously there are a few "ergonomic" differences to how these two functions operate. But I am wondering more about memory/cpu complexity.
My intuition is telling me that pass by reference is more performant as we are modifying memory in place and not allocating any resources on the stack.
I would guess though that in the case of pass-by-value and return there are some compiler optimizations that would come into play and perhaps make it equally as performant or very close.

I don't know much about Zig, but in C (as tagged) passing pointers around is as passing a single "number", while passing structures by value involves copying their whole content into different memory locations. Optimizations might be performed on the case-by-case basis, depending on the overall algorithm, but not in general.

It depends.  But generally, if the struct is smaller than a pointer, it is probably more efficient to pass the struct.  If the struct is larger than a pointer, it is probably more efficient to pass the pointer.  But there are many factors.

There is nothing like an objectively correct answer for all cases on all platforms. You need to benchmark, and look at what the compiler is doing with optimizations turned on.

If you are just scaling single vector, then it doesn't really matter which way you do it (unless you are on crappy 8-bit cpu, which you shouldn't be using anyway). But usually you are scaling multiple vectors, so you would pass them as arrays to avoid function call overhead and take advantage of SIMD instructions. And arrays wouldn't be passed by value.

What is "correct" depends on many factors.

numeric-like types, such as OP's Vec3 tend to favor by value
if pass-by-reference is not explicitly declared (*), Zig may still choose to do so (docs)
passing by value can be much worse with large objects
passing by reference may be slower, yet not too bad

Suggestion: if object is certainly small, use by value, else by reference.
When in doubt, see Is premature optimization really the root of all evil? and make effective use of your valuable time.

As of 0.12 all structs, even with just a single item, are passed by const pointer in zig. Also that vec3 is 12 bytes so rather small, but it has nothing to do with it being number types but the size of the struct. If the fields were f64 doubling the size it would probably be better to pass by pointer. There is no pass by reference in C or Zig. they don't have references like c++ does.

This is such an off the mark answer. Why would you think pass by pointer would be slower? You certainly going to hit the L1 cache and the indirection would likely be removed in the optimization. Even if not, passing by value would lilkely be a copy on the stack where you still need to generate an address. Some languages might pass very small structs in a register but zig doesn't do that.

@JasonNordwick -- "Structs, unions, and arrays can sometimes be more efficiently passed as a reference, since a copy could be arbitrarily expensive depending on the size. When these types are passed as parameters, Zig may choose to copy and pass by value, or pass by reference, whichever way Zig decides will be faster."

Zig currently doesn't do that AFAIK. In reality It always passes by pointer as of 0.11 and I don; think that changed in 0.12. While that may be a future plan, it doesn't currently. Still doesn't answer why the author thinks pass by pointer is more expensive. There are a couple things such as aliasing optimzations, but it isn't mentioned in the answer, and zig's pass by pointer under the hood might ruin those anyways.

First there is no references in Zig or C. This is pass by pointer. C++ has pass by reference for an example. References are pointers under the hood for the most part, but it is still pass by value but just the address is copies into the pointer.
If you need to modify the object, then you need to pass by pointer (or return it back out and reassign the original).
But passing by pointer does create an indirection that might be removed during optimization and will almost guarateed hit the L1 cache so not a worrying cost if even one. Unless you are working on a very constrained system.
Passing by copy would likely be a copy to the stack where an address still needs to be generated so not much different that pass by pointer except with the extra copy. The benefit to this is that you can guarantee no aliasing of value so the compiler might be able to generate slightly better code at times.
It will depend on your architecture you are working with, its register sizes and amount, and how it passes arguments. But you know if you are dealing with that stuff.
So for x86-64, the rule of thumb I use is small structs of 16 bytes or less (2 registers) I pass by value. C++ and other languages tend to make things like spans and string views fit in that size so they are passed by value. But this isn't a hard rule. Anything larger I generally default to pass by pointer.
Right now Zig passed all structs by const pointer unless that has changed in master, but I haven't heard anything about it, so you don't really get a choice in zig.

If we are being pedantic, C is pass by value only.

That's what I was trying to say when I said C has no references - passing the pointer by value. It isn't pedantic when languages closely related like c++ have true pass by reference.

"...there is no references in Zig or C." -- The concept of references has been around longer than C++. Pointers are one form of reference; after all, we dereference pointers, and it is common in C to talk about the "referenced object" of a pointer. I and others often call the pointer-passing idiom "simulated call by reference" when being pedantic. It is worthwhile to point out that C and Zig pass function parameters using call-by-value, but some of your comments seem too pedantic in that this observation doesn't clearly address the OP question.

Passing a pointer by value. That is not pass by reference. There is a clear definition of it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2229498/passing-by-reference-in-c Passing by reference is like c++ where you don't need to take the address and can still swap values. When inlined it doesn't even have to generate addresses. C, C#, Java, etc all descibe themselves as pass by value. Simulating something close isn't the same thing as that something. Im the only one that talks about aliasing which is the real issue that happens because the pass by copy will also be a passed by address on the stack too
